# How to access the previous/next element in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way to access a `list`'s (or `tuple`'s, or other iterable's) next or previous element while looping through it with a `for` loop?

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for item in l:
    if item == 2:
        get_previous(l, item)
```

Answer (score 78):

Expressed as a generator function:

```
def neighborhood(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    prev_item = None
    current_item = next(iterator)  # throws StopIteration if empty.
    for next_item in iterator:
        yield (prev_item, current_item, next_item)
        prev_item = current_item
        current_item = next_item
    yield (prev_item, current_item, None)
```

Usage:

```
for prev,item,next in neighborhood(l):
    print prev, item, next
```

Comment: I might do "prev, item = item, next" in this case.

Comment: To make this cycle infinitely (no StopIteration), do `from itertools import cycle` and change the second line to: `iterator = cycle(iterable)`

Comment: Is it less Pythonic to use enumerate in this context?

Comment: The answer you're looking for is Vicky Liau's, the one below this one. Or, if you want it to work on any iterable and not just lists/tuples/strs etc, the [one using `itertools`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41047005/3064538).

Comment: Just do `for prev, cur, nxt in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]):` instead of all this code. If you need to set `prev` and `nxt` to `None` for the first and last iteration, just do `l = [None, *l, None]` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Try to use this on an empty list causes a [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError) (because it throws a [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) error).

Comment: Throwing `StopIteration` is normal and expected for a generator function. When called in a `for`-loop, it will just terminate the loop.

Comment: @Boris "below this one" is not very precise because with the change in score of each answer they might go up or down. Were you talking about the answer from Vicky Lau?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. "The answer you're looking for is Vicky Liau's"

Comment: @Boris, worth noting though that your solution doesn't keep generators as generators - `l = [None, *l, None]` unpacks `l` into a list. The original solution keeps generators as generators, which might be what you want, e.g. for memory or side effects.

Comment: For python 3.10 - users there is ready to go function itertools.pairwise, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69584524/3361462

Answer (score 35):

```
l = [1, 2, 3]

for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]):
    print(i, j)
```

Comment: I used this, but expanded to avoid dropping the start/end items:  
`for prev,cur,next in zip([None]+l[:-1], l, l[1:]+[None]):`

Comment: You can avoid dropping the start/end items like this: `l = [None, *l, None]` and then `for prev, cur, nxt in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]):`

Answer (score 12):

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i, item in enumerate(l):
    if item == 2:
        previous = l[i - 1]
        print(previous)
```

Output:

```
1
```

This will wrap around and return the last item in the list if the item you're looking for is the first item in list. In other words changing the third line to `if item == 1:` in the above code will cause it to print `3`.

Comment: If your list is only one element long `l = [2]`, this will return the same element as the previous element.

Answer (score 10):

When dealing with generators where you need some context, I often use the below utility function to give a sliding window view on an iterator:

```
import collections, itertools

def window(it, winsize, step=1):
    """Sliding window iterator."""
    it=iter(it)  # Ensure we have an iterator
    l=collections.deque(itertools.islice(it, winsize))
    while 1:  # Continue till StopIteration gets raised.
        yield tuple(l)
        for i in range(step):
            l.append(it.next())
            l.popleft()
```

It'll generate a view of the sequence N items at a time, shifting step places over.  eg.

```
>>> list(window([1,2,3,4,5],3))
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

When using in lookahead/behind situations where you also need to deal with numbers without having a next or previous value, you may want pad the sequence with an appropriate value such as None.

```
l= range(10)
# Print adjacent numbers
for cur, next in window(l + [None] ,2):
    if next is None: print "%d is the last number." % cur
    else: print "%d is followed by %d" % (cur,next)
```

Comment: If you're using `itertools`, use Francisco Couzo's answer with [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41047005

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old, but why not just use `enumerate`?

```
l = ['adam', 'rick', 'morty', 'adam', 'billy', 'bob', 'wally', 'bob', 'jerry']

for i, item in enumerate(l):
    if i == 0:
        previous_item = None
    else:
        previous_item = l[i - 1]

    if i == len(l) - 1:
        next_item = None
    else:
        next_item = l[i + 1]

    print('Previous Item:', previous_item)
    print('Item:', item)
    print('Next Item:', next_item)
    print('')

    pass
```

If you run this you will see that it grabs previous and next items and doesn't care about repeating items in the list.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is fine and doesn't involve external libraries or special functions.

Comment: The question also asked for the previous item.  And won't this work incorrectly if an item repeats? `[1,2,1,3]`?

Comment: @Teepeemm, yeah, I will update it with a version that meets the requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the looper utility from the [Tempita project](http://pythonpaste.org/tempita/#bunch-and-looper). It gives you a wrapper object around the loop item that provides properties such as previous, next, first, last etc.

Take a look at the [source code](http://svn.pythonpaste.org/Tempita/trunk/tempita/_looper.py) for the looper class, it is quite simple. There are other such loop helpers out there, but I cannot remember any others right now.

Example:

```
> easy_install Tempita
> python
>>> from tempita import looper
>>> for loop, i in looper([1, 2, 3]):
...     print loop.previous, loop.item, loop.index, loop.next, loop.first, loop.last, loop.length, loop.odd, loop.even
... 
None 1 0 2 True False 3 True 0
1 2 1 3 False False 3 False 1
2 3 2 None False True 3 True 0
```

Comment: Links all broken.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the solution to work on iterables, the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has a recipe that does exactly what you want using [`itertools.tee()`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to import anything, here is an example of accessing the previous item of a generator with the for loop. It uses a class variable to store each next result before the following next call. This variable could be a small list if you wanted more than the immediately previous item. Inside the class is a method generator that effectively extends the next() builtin to include the previous item assignment.

Code (Python 3.10):

```
def previous():
    class Plusprev():
        def __init__(pp, gen=None):
            pp.g = gen
            pp.nxt = ''
            pp.prev = 'start'

        def ppnext(pp):
            while pp.nxt != 'done':
                pp.nxt = next(pp.g,'done')
                yield pp.nxt
                pp.prev = pp.nxt

    sqgen = (n*n for n in range(13))
    ppcl = Plusprev(sqgen)
    nxtg = ppcl.ppnext()
    nxt = next(nxtg,'done')
    while nxt != 'done':
        print('\nprevious ',ppcl.prev)
        print('current ',nxt)
        nxt = next(nxtg,'done')

previous()
```

This uses the builtin function, next(), default parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a straightforward way, especially because an iterable can be a [generator](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types) (no going back). You can do it with [sequences](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) by passing the index of the element into the loop body:

```
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    if index > 0:
        previous_item = l[index - 1]
    else:
        previous_item = None
```

The [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function is a builtin.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately previous?

You mean the following, right?

```
previous = None
for item in someList:
    if item == target: break
    previous = item
# previous is the item before the target
```

If you want *n* previous items, you can do this with a kind of circular queue of size *n*.

```
queue = []
for item in someList:
    if item == target: break
    queue .append( item )
    if len(queue ) > n: queue .pop(0)
if len(queue ) < n: previous = None
previous = previous[0]
# previous is *n* before the target
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I find it important to show a simple solution which works also with generators and other kind of iterables, not like most of the answers working only with list like objects. It is somewhat similar to Brian's answer and the solution here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/1754/itertools.tee

```
import itertools

iter0, iter1 = itertools.tee(iterable)

for item, next_item in itertools.zip_longest(
    iter0,
    itertools.islice(iter1, 1, None)
):

    do_something(item, next_item)
```

Alternatively, calling `next` on the second iterable (if you are sure it has at least one element):

```
import itertools

iter0, iter1 = itertools.tee(iterable)
_ = next(iter1)

for item, next_item in itertools.zip_longest(iter0, iter1):

    do_something(item, next_item)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who upgraded to python 3.10, such function was added directly to
[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)

```
import itertools

l = [1,2,3]
for x, y in itertools.pairwise(l):
    print(x, y)
# 1 2
# 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterators only have the next() method so you cannot look forwards or backwards, you can only get the next item.

enumerate(iterable) can be useful if you are iterating a list or tuple.

Answer (score -2):

Not very pythonic, but gets it done and is simple:

```
l=[1,2,3]
for index in range(len(l)):
    if l[index]==2:
        l[index-1]
```

TO DO: protect the edges

Comment: This is exactly the same as @Rudiger Wolf's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/324273

Answer (score -7):

The most simple way is to search the list for the item:

```
def get_previous(l, item):
    idx = l.find(item)
    return None if idx == 0 else l[idx-1]
```

Of course, this only works if the list only contains unique items. The other solution is:

```
for idx in range(len(l)):
    item = l[idx]
    if item == 2:
        l[idx-1]
```