# How can I iterate over overlapping (current, next) pairs of values from a list?

Tags: python

I sometimes need to iterate a list in Python looking at the "current" element and the "next" element. I have, till now, done so with code like:

```
for current, next in zip(the_list, the_list[1:]):
    # Do something
```

This works and does what I expect, but is there's a more idiomatic or efficient way to do the same thing?

---

<sub>Some answers to this problem can simplify by addressing the *specific* case of taking only two elements at a time. For the *general* case of N elements at a time, see [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/).</sub>

Comment: Check MizardX answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323750/how-to-access-previous-next-element-while-for-looping). But i don't think this solution is more idiomatic than yours.

Comment: Take a look at [Build a Basic Python Iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator).

Comment: since no one else has mentioned it, I'll be that guy, and point out that using `next` this way masks a built-in.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The [documentation for 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) provides this recipe:

```
import itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0, s1), (s1, s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

For Python 2, use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` to get the same kind of lazy iterator (`zip` will instead create a list):

```
import itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0, s1), (s1, s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)
```

How this works:

First, two parallel iterators, `a` and `b` are created (the `tee()` call), both pointing to the first element of the original iterable. The second iterator, `b` is moved 1 step  forward (the `next(b, None)`) call). At this point `a` points to s0 and `b` points to s1. Both `a` and `b` can traverse the original iterator independently - the izip function takes the two iterators and makes pairs of the returned elements, advancing both iterators at the same pace.

Since `tee()` can take an `n` parameter (the number of iterators to produce), the same technique can be adapted to produce a larger "window". For example:

```
def threes(iterator):
    "s -> (s0, s1, s2), (s1, s2, s3), (s2, s3, 4), ..."
    a, b, c = itertools.tee(iterator, 3)
    next(b, None)
    next(c, None)
    next(c, None)
    return zip(a, b, c)
```

Caveat: If one of the iterators produced by `tee` advances further than the others,  then the implementation needs to keep the consumed elements in memory until every iterator has consumed them (it cannot 'rewind' the original iterator). Here it doesn't matter because one iterator is only 1 step ahead of the other, but in general it's easy to use a lot of memory this way.

Comment: `zip(ł, ł[1:])` is much shorter and pythonic

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ: No, it doesn't work on every iterable and makes an unnecessary copy when used on lists. Using functions is pythonic.

Comment: This function implemented in `funcy` module: `funcy.pairwise`: https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/seqs.html#pairwise

Comment: Note: As of 3.10, [`pairwise` is provided directly in `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) (equivalent to the `pairwise` recipe, but pushed completely to the C layer, making it faster on the CPython reference interpreter).

Comment: Note that a fully general `windowed` recipe can be made by combining the `consume` recipe with your `threes`, by replacing the copy-pasted calls to `next` with a simple loop (done without unpacking the result of `tee`): `teed_iters = itertools.tee(iterator, n)`, `for i, it in enumerate(teed_iters): consume(it, i)`, `return zip(*teed_iters)`.

Comment: If you need the interval between indexes you can use this list comprehension:
a = [1, 9, 15, 25];
d = [aa-bb for aa,bb in zip(a[1:], a[:-1])];
print(d) => [8, 6, 10]  # i.e. 9-1, 15-9, and 25-15

Answer (score 58):

Roll your own!

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    a = next(it, None)

    for b in it:
        yield (a, b)
        a = b
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Has this been immortalized as a python method, or do we need to keep rolling?

Comment: @uhoh: Hasn’t yet as far as I know!

Comment: I'm surprised this is not the accepted answer. No imports and the logic behind it is very easy to understand. +1 definitely.

Comment: It will soon be included as [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) in 3.10 !

Comment: And add `yield(a, None)` if you also wish to get the last item.

Answer (score 49):

Starting in Python 3.10, this is the exact role of the [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html?highlight=pairwise#itertools.pairwise) function:

```
from itertools import pairwise

list(pairwise([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
# [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

or simply `pairwise([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` if you don't need the result as a `list`.

Answer (score 31):

I’m just putting this out, **I’m very surprised no one has thought of enumerate().**

```
for (index, thing) in enumerate(the_list):
    if index < len(the_list):
        current, next_ = thing, the_list[index + 1]
        #do something
```

Comment: Actually, the `if` can also be removed if you use slicing: `for (index, thing) in enumerate(the_list[:-1]): current, next_ = thing, the_list[index + 1]`

Comment: This should really be the answer, it doesn't rely on any extra imports and works great.

Comment: Though, it does not work for non-indexable iterables so it's not a generic solution.

Comment: I think OP's approach is cleaner, honestly.

Answer (score 24):

Since `the_list[1:]` actually creates a copy of the whole list (excluding its first element), and `zip()` creates a list of tuples immediately when called,  in total three copies of your list are created.  If your list is very large, you might prefer

```
from itertools import izip, islice
for current_item, next_item in izip(the_list, islice(the_list, 1, None)):
    print(current_item, next_item)
```

which does not copy the list at all.

Comment: note that in python 3.x izip is suppressed of itertools and you should use builtin zip

Comment: Actually, doesn't `the_list[1:]` just create a slice object rather than a copy of almost the whole list -- so the OP's technique isn't quite as wasteful as you make it sound.

Comment: I think `[1:]` creates the slice object (or possibly "`1:`"), which is passed to `__slice__` on the list, which then returns a copy containing only the selected elements. One idiomatic way to copy a list is `l_copy = l[:]` (which I find ugly and unreadable -- prefer `l_copy = list(l)`)

Comment: @dcrosta: I think you're right about the `1:` being the slice object, so I stand corrected.

Comment: @dcrosta: There is no `__slice__` special method.  `the_list[1:]` is equivalent to `the_list[slice(1, None)]`, which in turn is equivalent to `list.__getitem__(the_list, slice(1, None))`.

Comment: @sven OK -- good point, and thanks for correcting. I don't know all the magic methods that well...

Comment: @martineau: The copy created by `the_list[1:]` is only a shallow copy, so it consists only of one pointer per list item.  The more memory intensive part is the `zip()` itself, because it will create a list of one `tuple` instance per list item, each of which will contain two pointers to the two items and some additional information.  This list will consume nine times the amount of memory the copy caused by `[1:]` consumes.

Comment: This also doesn't work if "the_list" is an iterator, since both izip and islice would consume the same one.

Answer (score 17):

Iterating by index can do the same thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in xrange(len(the_list) - 1):
    current_item, next_item = the_list[i], the_list[i + 1]
    print(current_item, next_item)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

Comment: Your answer was more *previous* and *current* instead of *current* and *next*, as in the question. I made an edit improving the semantics so that `i` is always the index of the current element.

Answer (score 5):

I am really surprised nobody has mentioned the shorter, simpler and most importantly *general* solution:

Python 3:

```
from itertools import islice

def n_wise(iterable, n):
    return zip(*(islice(iterable, i, None) for i in range(n)))
```

Python 2:

```
from itertools import izip, islice

def n_wise(iterable, n):
    return izip(*(islice(iterable, i, None) for i in xrange(n)))
```

It works for pairwise iteration by passing `n=2`, but can handle any higher number:

```
>>> for a, b in n_wise('Hello!', 2):
>>>     print(a, b)
H e
e l
l l
l o
o !

>>> for a, b, c, d in n_wise('Hello World!', 4):
>>>     print(a, b, c, d)
H e l l
e l l o
l l o
l o   W
o   W o
  W o r
W o r l
o r l d
r l d !
```

Comment: We have a canonical duplicate for the general version: [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/). It does appear that that question is slightly newer.

Answer (score 3):

**This is now a simple Import As of 16th May 2020**

```
from more_itertools import pairwise
for current, next in pairwise(your_iterable):
  print(f'Current = {current}, next = {nxt}')
```

[Docs for more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/)
Under the hood this code is the same as that in the other answers, but I much prefer imports when available.

If you don't already have it installed then:
`pip install more-itertools`

**Example**

For instance if you had the fibbonnacci sequence, you could calculate the ratios of subsequent pairs as:

```
from more_itertools import pairwise
fib= [1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
for current, nxt in pairwise(fib):
    ratio=current/nxt
    print(f'Curent = {current}, next = {nxt}, ratio = {ratio} ')
```

Comment: "This is now a simple Import" - well no, not really, as `more_itertools` is an external package that needs to be installed...

Comment: True, but at the same time more-itertools such an incredibly useful library that I recommend most Python programmers at least look into it.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, `itertools.pairwise()` is the way to go on recent versions of Python. However, for 3.8+, a fun and somewhat more concise (compared to the other solutions that have been posted) option that does not require an extra import comes via the [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
  a = next(iterable)
  yield from ((a, a := b) for b in iterable)
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution:

```
def neighbors( list ):
  i = 0
  while i + 1 < len( list ):
    yield ( list[ i ], list[ i + 1 ] )
    i += 1

for ( x, y ) in neighbors( list ):
  print( x, y )
```

Answer (score 0):

Pairs from a list using a list comprehension

```
the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pairs = [[the_list[i], the_list[i + 1]] for i in range(len(the_list) - 1)]
for [current_item, next_item] in pairs:
    print(current_item, next_item)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp=[-39.5, -27.5, -15.5, -3.5, 8.5, 20.5, 32.5, 44.5, 56.5, 68.5, 80.5, 92.5,104.5]

li_tup = []
count=0
i=0
new_tup=()
while i<len(temp):
    if count<1:
        new_tup = new_tup + (temp[i],)
        count=count+1
        i=i+1
    else:
        new_tup = new_tup + (temp[i],)
        count=0
        li_tup.append(new_tup)
        new_tup=()
print(li_tup)
```

One way to do it would be as above

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
code = '0016364ee0942aa7cc04a8189ef3'
# Getting the current and next item
print  [code[idx]+code[idx+1] for idx in range(len(code)-1)]
# Getting the pair
print  [code[idx*2]+code[idx*2+1] for idx in range(len(code)/2)]
```