# Print current value and next value during iteration in Python

Tags: python, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python)

While iterating a list, I want to print the current item in the list, plus the next value in the list.

```
listOfStuff = [a,b,c,d,e]
for item in listOfStuff:
    print item, <nextItem>
```

The output would be:

```
a b
b c
c d
d e
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I found was:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for i,nexti in zip(a,a[1::]):
    print i,nexti
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfStuff = ['a','b','c','d','e']
for i, item in enumerate(listOfStuff[:-1]):
    next_item = listOfStuff[i+1]
    print item, next_item
```

Comment: You don't need `enumerate`. `for item in listOfStuff[:-1]:`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for i in range(1, len(listOfStuff)):
    print listOfStuff[i - 1], listOfStuff[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
def double_iter(iter):
    a = next(iter)
    for item in iter
        yield (a, item)
        a = item

double_iter(original_iter)
```