# finding frequent string patterns using python

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics

So I am trying to do this problem where I have to find the most frequent 6-letter string within some lines in python, so I realize one could do something like this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter("ACGTGCA")
>>> x
Counter({'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'G': 2, 'T': 1})
```

Now then, the data I'm using is DNA files and the format of a file goes something like this:

```
> name of the protein
ACGTGCA ... < more sequences> 
ACGTGCA ... < more sequences> 
ACGTGCA ... < more sequences> 
ACGTGCA ... < more sequences> 

> another protein 
AGTTTCAGGAC ... <more sequences>
AGTTTCAGGAC ... <more sequences>
AGTTTCAGGAC ... <more sequences>
AGTTTCAGGAC ... <more sequences>
```

We can start by going one protein at a time, but then how does one modify the block of code above to search for the most frequent 6-character string pattern? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest way is just do this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> protein = "AGTTTCAGGAC"
>>> Counter(protein[i:i+6] for i in range(len(protein)-5))
Counter({'TTCAGG': 1, 'AGTTTC': 1, 'CAGGAC': 1, 'TCAGGA': 1, 'GTTTCA': 1, 'TTTCAG': 1})
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot Duncan, that was surprisingly elegant. I hope you don't mind if I ask a follow-up question: How would I go about ranking them, what I posted here was just an example, the actual sequence are much longer, lets say I wanna see the top 4 most frequent 6-char. strings, how would I add up their counters? Thanks again!

Comment: @dhillonv10: `Counter.most_common` (http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common). There are many useful methods on `Counter` objects.

Comment: Thanks @katrielalex, I was going to suggest `heapq.nlargest` but yours is the correct answer.

Comment: yea on that note, Counter.most_common already sorts out the results.

Comment: What if there are more strings of length 6?

Answer (score 4):

The [old itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/lib/itertools-example.html) (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7636054/398968)) provide the `window` function, which is a generic version of @Duncan's answer.

```
def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result
```

Then you can just do

```
collections.Counter(window(x))
```

Personally I'd still go with string slicing, but this is a generic version if you want it.

Comment: Interesting, but note that it gives you tuples instead of strings which may or may not matter.

Comment: Indeed! You can do `map("".join, Counter(window(x)).most_common(n))` if you want strings.