# Generate a list of strings with a sliding window using itertools, yield, and iter() in Python 2.7.1?

Tags: python, string, loops, sliding-window

I'm trying to generate a sliding window function in Python.  I figured out how to do it but not all inside the function. itertools, yield, and iter() are entirely new to me.

i want to input

```
a='abcdefg'
b=window(a,3)
print b
['abc','bcd','cde','def','efg']
```

the way i got it work was

```
def window(fseq, window_size=5):
    import itertools
    tentative=[]
    final=[]
    iteration=iter(fseq)
    value=tuple(itertools.islice(iteration,window_size))
    if len(value) == window_size:
        yield value
    for element in iteration:
        value = value[1:] + (element,)
        yield value

a='abcdefg'
result=window(a)
list1=[]
for k in result:
    list1.append(k)
list2=[]   
for j in list1:
    tentative=''.join(j)
    list2.append(tentative)
print list2
```

basically what im confused about is how to use the final value of the function inside the function?

here is my code for the function

```
def window(fseq, window_size=5):
    import itertools
    tentative=[]
    final=[]
    iteration=iter(fseq)
    value=tuple(itertools.islice(iteration,window_size))
    if len(value) == window_size:
        yield value
    for element in iteration:
        value = value[1:] + (element,)
        yield value
    for k in value:
        tentative.append(k)
    for j in tentative:
        tentative_string=''.join(j)
        final.append(tentative_string)
    return final



seq='abcdefg'
uence=window(seq)
print uence
```

i want it to return the joined list but when i press run it, it says "There's an error in your program *** 'return' with argument inside generator"

I'm really confused . . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python split string in moving window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636004/python-split-string-in-moving-window)

Comment: Dude... are you going to post the same question every 8 hours? :o

Comment: My bad i thought i would of been able to delete the other

Comment: It would still have been wrong: if you ask a question and you don't get answers chances are: (1) you formulated it poorly [ → edit it ] - (2) it's a difficult question [ → answer yourself some question, get reputation points and place a bounty on it ]. Reposting to gain attention is not a welcome behaviour on SO (although I am positive you did not do it with the intention of doing any harm!) :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You mean you want to do this ? :

```
a='abcdefg'
b = [a[i:i+3] for i in xrange(len(a)-2)]
print b
['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg']
```

Comment: Shall we use range instead of xrange for more compatibility with python 3 ?

Comment: @ClementH. original OP was about a python2.7 installation, so, in this case, `xrange` was the best (for memory consumption). Yet, in python3, `range` would be the best solution. If you don't have too big number to iterate on, keep `range` everywhere, otherwise, use [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/).

Answer (score 7):

Your generator could be much shorter:

```
def window(fseq, window_size=5):
    for i in xrange(len(fseq) - window_size + 1):
        yield fseq[i:i+window_size]


for seq in window('abcdefghij', 3):
    print seq


abc
bcd
cde
def
efg
fgh
ghi
hij
```

Comment: this is definitely the better option. i didn't know what generators were at the time and didnt have to deal with large datasets like i do now

Comment: In python3, `xrange` is now just `range`

Answer (score 2):

Use zip function in one line code:

```
  [ "".join(j) for j in zip(*[fseq[i:] for i in range(window_size)])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def window(fseq,fn):
    alpha=[fseq[i:i+fn] for i in range(len(fseq)-(fn-1))]
    return alpha
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your input or expected output are, but you cannot mix `yield` and `return` in one function. change `return` to `yield` and your function will not throw that error again.

```
def window(fseq, window_size=5):
    ....
        final.append(tentative_string)
    yield final
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>def window(data, win_size):
...    tmp = [iter(data[i:]) for i in range(win_size)]
...    return zip(*tmp)
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> window(a, 3)
>>>[(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), (4,5,6)]
```