# Print a word in parts python

Tags: python, regex, printing, substitution

Hello I want to make a function that will use enhance(which just changes the word already made it) and print the new word in parts of a given number n. Example for S=test I should get (‘##t’, ‘#te’, ‘tes’, ‘est’, ‘st%’, ‘t%%’)

```
def enhance(S,n):
    S = "#"*(n-1)+S+"%"*(n-1)
    return S

def exploder(S,n):
    S = enhance(S,n)
    x=0
    for i in range (n <= len(S)):
        print(S[x:i])
        x=x+1


S="test"
n = 3
for n in range (0,n):
    print(exploder(S,n))
    n=n+1
print(exploder(S,n))
```

Comment: And where is a question?

Comment: Looks similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408117/generate-a-list-of-strings-with-a-sliding-window-using-itertools-yield-and-ite

Answer (score 2):

One immediate fix.  Instead of:

```
  for i in range (n <= len(S)):
```

I think you want:

```
  for i in range(n, len(S) + 1):
```

That will give you values of *i* in the range `n <= i < len(s)`.

Also, as Alex Hall suggested, change:

```
print(exploder(S,n))
```

To just:

```
exploder(S,n)
```

The *exploder* function was returning *None*. So that print is the source your spurious *None* outputs.

Comment: This works but I get one more None print. Sorry I am new to python

Comment: @Alex just call `exploder`, don't `print` it, since you're printing what it returns which is nothing. `exploder` does the printing on its own.

Comment: @Alex correctly identified the second problem with the code.  The ``print(exploder(S,n))`` is where the ``None`` outputs were coming from.

Answer (score 1):

```
def enhance(S, n):
    S = "#" * (n - 1) + S + "%" * (n - 1)
    return S

def exploder(S, n):
    S = enhance(S, n)
    for i in range(len(S)-n+1):
        print(S[i:i+n])

S = "test"
n = 3
exploder(S, n)
```

Output:

```
##t
#te
tes
est
st%
t%%
```

Comment: But this way I dont get a t%% print the last one.

Comment: @Alex oops, didn't notice. You just have to add one to the range of `i`, as I've [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42805509/revisions).