# DNA sequence into feature

Tags: python, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I have a dataset contains DNA sequences, and I want to convert them into a numerical representation. As in this document:

[image: DNA to Binary]

- What is this process (the converting), I want to search about it?
- How can I apply it in python?
- can it be done to a large array, as a dataset input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the process you're referring to is [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot). You'll first want to transform your DNA sequence into a sequence of 3bp words using a sliding window of width 3. see here: [Generate a list of strings with a sliding window using itertools, yield, and iter() in Python 2.7.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408117/generate-a-list-of-strings-with-a-sliding-window-using-itertools-yield-and-ite)

So you should have something like a list of DNA "words" (e.g. `['aaa', 'tgc']`)Then you'll want to convert each of the words into a vector. One way to do this is to create a dictionary with keys corresponding to all possible words and values with the one-hot representation. Then you can simply convert each word to its corresponding vector using a list comprehension and dictionary look-up. That might not be the most efficient way to do it, but it's a start. sklearn has [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), but it only works on integers.

See also https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/