# Processing a large .txt file in python efficiently

Tags: python, tabs, sliding-window, delimited

I am quite new to python and programming in general, but I am trying to run a "sliding window" calculation over a tab delimited .txt file that contains about 7 million lines with python. What I mean by sliding window is that it will run a calculation over say 50,000 lines, report the number and then move up say 10,000 lines and perform the same calculation over another 50,000 lines. I have the calculation and the "sliding window" working correctly and it runs well if I test it on a a small subset of my data. However, if i try to run the program over my entire data set it is incredibly slow (i've had it running now for about 40 hours). The math is quite simple so I don't think it should be taking this long.

The way I am reading my .txt file right now is with the csv.DictReader module. My code is as follows:

```
file1='/Users/Shared/SmallSetbee.txt'
newfile=open(file1, 'rb')
reader=csv.DictReader((line.replace('\0','') for line in newfile), delimiter="\t")
```

I believe that this is making a dictionary out of all 7 million lines at once, which I'm thinking could be the reason it slows down so much for the larger file.

Since I am only interested in running my calculation over "chunks" or "windows" of data at a time, is there a more efficient way to read in only specified lines at a time, perform the calculation and then repeat with a new specified "chunk" or "window" of specified lines?

Comment: This does not make a dictionary of all lines at once.  It makes a dictionary for each line.  This means that the snippet you posted is not the cause of your performance woes.  Perhaps you could show us some more code?

Comment: I suspect that if you're doing calculations over large sets of table-like data you might want to look at Pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk  Everything you're trying to do has probably already been done before 1000 times better.

Comment: You will run this calculation on 696 "windows".  How long does it take for a single window on a 50k line file?

Comment: Do you always move the "window" up by a fixed size or a multiple of a fixed size number of lines. Also what version of Python are you  using?

Comment: Profile your code and see exactly where it's spending most of its time.

Comment: see [`sliding_window(iterable, size, step, fillvalue)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13408251/4279)

Answer (score 6):

A `collections.deque` is an ordered collection of items which can take a maximum size. When you add an item to one end, one falls of the other end. This means that to iterate over a "window" on your csv, you just need to keep adding rows to the `deque` and it will handle throwing away complete ones already.

```
dq = collections.deque(maxlen=50000)
with open(...) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader((line.replace("\0", "") for line in csv_file), delimiter="\t")

    # initial fill
    for _ in range(50000):
        dq.append(reader.next())

    # repeated compute
    try:
        while 1:
            compute(dq)
            for _ in range(10000):
                dq.append(reader.next())
    except StopIteration:
            compute(dq)
```

Comment: `try/except` should be closer to `reader.next()` to avoid accidentally catching `StopIteration` from `compute(dq)`

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `csv.DictReader`, instead use `csv.reader`.  It takes longer to create a dictionary for each row than it takes to create a list for each row.  Additionally, it is marginally faster to access a list by an index than it is to access a dictionary by a key.

I timed iteration over a 300,000 line 4 column csv file using the two csv readers.  `csv.DictReader` took **seven times longer** than a `csv.reader`.

Combine this with [katrielalex's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13401920/1322401) to use `collections.deque` and you should see a nice speedup.

Additionally, [profile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code to pinpoint where you are spending most of your time.