# Generating a path from an iterable of points

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iterable

Suppose I have a set `{a, b, c, d}`. I want to create a "path" from it, which is a generator that yields  `(a, b)`, then `(b, c)`, then `(c, d)` (of course `set` is unordered, so any other path through the elements is acceptable).

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using the `pairwise()` recipe from http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
...     a, b = tee(iterable)
...     next(b, None)
...     return zip(a, b)
...
>>> for pair in pairwise({1, 2, 3, 4}):
...     print(pair)
...
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def gen(seq):
   it = iter(seq)
   a, b = next(it), next(it)
   while True:
     yield (a, b)
     a, b = b, next(it)

print(list(gen({1, 2, 3, 4})))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Rolling or sliding window iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6822725) solution:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> def window(seq, n=2):
...     "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
...     "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
...     it = iter(seq)
...     result = tuple(islice(it, n))
...     if len(result) == n:
...         yield result    
...     for elem in it:
...         result = result[1:] + (elem,)
...         yield result
... 
>>> path = window({1, 2, 3, 4})
>>> for step in gen:
...     print path
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

This happens to follow sorted order, because for python integers `hash(x) == x` and thus the sequence of 1, 2, 3, 4 is inserted in that order into the set.

Comment: I like this recipe, even though it's more general than I need. I wonder why this recipe was replaced with another one in the current `itertools` documentation?

Comment: @max: It was replaced with the [`pairwise` recipe to illustrate `tee`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/ea058504104c). The recipes are there to show off the functions of the module, and `tee()` was yet to be used on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `pairwise` [itertools recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
        a, b = tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return zip(a, b)

>>> pairwise({1, 2, 3, 4})
<zip object at 0x0000000003B34D88>
>>> list(_)
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand the question

```
from itertools import islice
a = {'A','B','C','D'}
zip(a,islice(a,1,None))
#[('A', 'C'), ('C', 'B'), ('B', 'D')]
```