# Filtering a list in python using a function of other values in the list.

Tags: python, list, function, filter

```
counts = misc. array

    for i in counts:
        if i < "(sum of the two integers next to i)/4"
            return -1
```

What I am trying to do is set all values in the list which are less than half the average of their two neighbours to -1.  i.e. for the list [10., 20., 10., 25., 30.] if i=3 then I want to see if 10 is less than (20+25)/4 and since that is 45/4 > 10  I want to then set 10 equal to -1. I will then filter for all values in the list >= 0.

This is further complicated by the fact that you should start with i+1 because this process doesn't work with the first value and then you should end with -1 because this process doesn't work with the last value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could borrow the sliding window generator from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/367273), and put it to use like so:

```
out = [y if y >= (x+z)/4. else -1 for x,y,z in window(l, 3)]
```

where `l` is your list.

This chops off the first and the last element. It would be easy to do something different to them (e.g. set to -1) if you so wish.

Comment: how does that help user(new_user_number) who just about asked his first question? Not that my answer is the greatest...

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want (assuming values are in list `data`)?

```
filtered = [data[i] for i in range(1,len(data)-1) if data[i] >= (data[i+1]+data[i-1])/4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
result = [(x+1 if counts[x] > counts[x-1]/counts[x+1]/4 else -1) for x in range(len(counts[1:-1]))]
```

- `x` is a idex in counts  --> **for x in range(len(counts[1:-1])**
- `x+1` because we know counts[0] and count[-1] are out. Hence to achieve result one must **adjust it**.
- `if count[x] > counts[x-1]/counts[x+1]/4 else -1` test, returns the result if result is True, otherwise -1
note the `> 0`, it's opposite to what you want
- `for x in range(len(counts[1:-1]))`
because we know first and last value is of no matter
- `counts[1:-1]` as above, always better to use a copy of a list, thread-safe

This should work, will give you a list of valid `(!=-1)` and invalid `(== -1)` results per index in count,

question is, what can you do further with the result?

you can test, e.g.: (mind the **adjusted** *x* in result)

```
 ['N/A'] + [(x if x!= -1 else False) for x in result] + ['N/A']
```

which gives you a mirror image of counts with either False or True result

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that doesn't look too elegant, but I believe is correct and understandable. The filtering is included, so it will also work if -1 is an allowed value.

I use 3 variables (a,b and i), and 3 flag variables (fa, fb and fi) which show if the value needs to be included in the result set or not.

```
def test(lst):
    a, fa, b, fb, res  = None, False, None, False, []
    for i in lst:
        if a is not None:
            fi = b < (a + i)/4
        else:
            fi = True
        if fa:
            res.append(a)
        a, fa = b, fb
        b, fb = i, fi
    if fa:
        res.append(a)
    res.append(b)
    return res

print(test([10., 20., 10., 25., 30.]))
=> [10.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0]
```