# Identifying two consecutive identical lines and replace the first one

Tags: python

I have the following input file structure, with text on each line :

```
line1
line2
line3
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

When two lines are exactly the same i.e. line 3 I want to keep the second one and change the content of the first to be "SECTION MISSING". I do not manage to put it at the right place. The closest I get to is with the code below but the output I get is :

```
line1
line2
line3
SECTION MISSING
line4
etc.
```

While I want:

```
line1
line2
SECTION MISSING
line3 
line4
```

Code:

```
def uniq(iterator):
    previous = float("NaN")  # Not equal to anything
    section=("SECTION : MISSING\n")
    for value in iterator:
        if previous == value:
            yield section
        else:
            yield value
            previous = value
    return;

 with open('infile.txt','r') as file:
    with open('outfile.txt','w') as f:
        for line in uniq(file):
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: You can apply a sliding window iterator to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
prev = None
with open('infile.txt','r') as fi:
    with open('outfile.txt','w') as fo:
        for line in fi:
            if prev is not None: 
                fo.write(prev if prev != line else "SECTION : MISSING\n")
            prev = line
        fo.write(prev)
```

Will give you the output file you're looking for:

```
line1
line2
SECTION : MISSING
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

Comment: You should really check for `None` by identity - `if prev is not None:` (see [PEP-008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations))

Comment: @jonsharpe, I thought about that too, but then thought that the EOL would resolve this.  But your comment made me reconsider (eg the last line in the file).  Updating answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to yield `previous`, rather than `value`:

```
def uniq(iterator):
    previous = None
    section = ("SECTION : MISSING\n")
    for value in iterator:
        if previous == value:
            yield section
        elif previous is not None:
            yield previous
        previous = value
    if previous is not None:
        yield previous
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list(uniq([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]))
[1, 'SECTION : MISSING\n', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'SECTION : MISSING\n', 6]
```

Comment: Certainly looping again (first on the input file lines, then again in `uniq`) isn't necessary or efficient.

Comment: @jedwards when does the OP's code loop on the input file lines *except* inside `uniq`?

Answer (score 0):

Personal preference for tasks like these, I use two cursors instead of one:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
with open(infile) as r, open(outfile, 'w') as w:
    p, c = tee(r)
    w.write(next(c))
    for prev,cur in izip(p,c):
        w.write(cur if prev!=cur else 'SECTION : MISSING\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you ever have to handle the situation with *three* consecutive lines (well, two or more) where you only want to replace the first one, you could use `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice, chain

def detect_missing(source):
    grouped = groupby(source)
    section = "SECTION: MISSING\n"
    for _, group in grouped:
        first_two = list(islice(group, 2))
        if len(first_two) > 1:
            first_two[0] = section
        yield from chain(first_two, group)
```

(Python 3, but you could remove the `yield from` if you wanted.)