# compare current item to next item in a python list

Tags: python

Considering a python list, how can I compare current item to next it ? for example:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3]
for i in mylist:        
    if i == next item:
       replace (both i and next item) with "same value"

 >>> [1, "same value", "same value", 4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: The generic solution is: [Rolling or sliding window iterator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6822725)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use enumerate:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3]
for i, j in enumerate(mylist[:-1]):
    if j  == mylist[i+1]: 
        mylist[i] = "foo" 
        mylist[i+1] = "foo"
print mylist
[1, 'foo', 'foo', 4, 2, 3]
```

`j` is the current element in the iteration, `mylist[i+1]` is the next, if `j=4`,`mylist[i+1] = 2` etc.. `mylist[:-1]` loops through all the elements except the last so the last `mylist[i+1]` get the last element in the list.