# getting successive adjacent elements of a list

Tags: python

I'm looking to create successive word sequence combinations from a list.

```
news = ['Brendan', 'Rodgers', 'has', 'wasted', 'no', 'time', 'in', 'playing', 'mind', '
games', 'with', 'Louis', 'van', 'Gaal', 'by', 'warning', 'the', 'new', 'Manchest
er', 'United', 'manager', 'that', 'the', 'competitive', 'nature', 'of', 'the', '
Premier', 'League', 'will', 'make', 'it', 'extremely', 'difficult', 'for', 'the'
, 'Dutchman', 'to', 'win', 'the', 'title', 'in', 'his', 'first', 'season.']
```

The following code I guess is not efficient. Is there a one-liner or a more pythonic way of achieving this?

```
wordseq = []
for i,j in enumerate(news):
    if len(news)-1 != i:
        wordseq.append((j, news[i+1]))
```

The result I want is this;

```
[('Brendan', 'Rodgers'), ('Rodgers', 'has'), ('has', 'wasted'), ('wasted', 'no')
, ('no', 'time'), ('time', 'in'), ('in', 'playing'), ('playing', 'mind'), ('mind
', 'games'), ('games', 'with'), ('with', 'Louis'), ('Louis', 'van'), ('van', 'Ga
al'), ('Gaal', 'by'), ('by', 'warning'), ('warning', 'the'), ('the', 'new'), ('n
ew', 'Manchester'), ('Manchester', 'United'), ('United', 'manager'), ('manager',
 'that'), ('that', 'the'), ('the', 'competitive'), ('competitive', 'nature'), ('
nature', 'of'), ('of', 'the'), ('the', 'Premier'), ('Premier', 'League'), ('Leag
ue', 'will'), ('will', 'make'), ('make', 'it'), ('it', 'extremely'), ('extremely
', 'difficult'), ('difficult', 'for'), ('for', 'the'), ('the', 'Dutchman'), ('Du
tchman', 'to'), ('to', 'win'), ('win', 'the'), ('the', 'title'), ('title', 'in')
, ('in', 'his'), ('his', 'first'), ('first', 'season.'), ('Brendan', 'Rodgers'),
 ('Rodgers', 'has'), ('has', 'wasted'), ('wasted', 'no'), ('no', 'time'), ('time
', 'in'), ('in', 'playing'), ('playing', 'mind'), ('mind', 'games'), ('games', '
with'), ('with', 'Louis'), ('Louis', 'van'), ('van', 'Gaal'), ('Gaal', 'by'), ('
by', 'warning'), ('warning', 'the'), ('the', 'new'), ('new', 'Manchester'), ('Ma
nchester', 'United'), ('United', 'manager'), ('manager', 'that'), ('that', 'the'
), ('the', 'competitive'), ('competitive', 'nature'), ('nature', 'of'), ('of', '
the'), ('the', 'Premier'), ('Premier', 'League'), ('League', 'will'), ('will', '
make'), ('make', 'it'), ('it', 'extremely'), ('extremely', 'difficult'), ('diffi
cult', 'for'), ('for', 'the'), ('the', 'Dutchman'), ('Dutchman', 'to'), ('to', '
win'), ('win', 'the'), ('the', 'title'), ('title', 'in'), ('in', 'his'), ('his',
 'first'), ('first', 'season.')]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rolling or sliding window iterator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `zip`:

```
wordseq = zip(news,news[1:])
```

Comment: Just to make it better, I would have used `itertools.izip` and `itertools.islice`. That should improve speed & memory usage.

Comment: `zip` itself is iterable in python 3. `islice` is still around though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip(news[:-1], news[1:])`

Comment: why `[:-1]`? its unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
wordseq = [(news[i-1], news[i]) for i in range(1, len(news))]
```