# Python: Grab text before and after a keyword

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, substring

```
keywords = ("banana", "apple", "orange", ...)
before = 50
after = 100
TEXT = "a big text string,  i.e., a page of a book"

for k in keywords:
    if k in TEXT:
        #cut = portion of text starting 'beforeText' chars before occurrence of 'k' and ending 'afterText' chars after occurrence of 'k'
        #finalcut = 'cut' with first and last WORDS trimmed to assure starting words are not cut in the middle
```

Guys, could you help me coding `cut` and `finalcut` string variables in the above example?

What is the most efficient solution considering I'm dealing with big texts, numerous pages and maybe more than 20 keywords to search?

Comment: If `TEXT` is, say, "Batman grappled with the Joker", do you want it to match the "apple" in the middle of "grappled"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all matches in a string using [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer). Each of the match objects has a [`start()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) method you can use to figure out the position in the string. You also won't need to check if the key is in the string, because then `finditer` returns an empty iterator:

```
keywords = ("banana", "apple", "orange", ...)
before = 50
after = 100
TEXT = "a big text string,  i.e., a page of a book"

for k in keywords:
    for match in re.finditer(k, TEXT):
        position = match.start()
        cut = TEXT[max(position - before, 0):position + after] # max is needed because that index must not be negative
        trimmed_match = re.match("\w*?\W+(.*)\W+\w*", cut, re.MULTILINE)
        finalcut = trimmed_match.group(1)
```

The regex trims everything up to and including the first sequence of non-word chars and everything from and including the last sequence of non-word characters (I added `re.MULTILINE` in case there are newlines in your text)

Comment: Note that keywords might be trimmed as well if they're the first or last word in the text

Answer (score 3):

You need to adjust your algorithm.  As written it is O(n*m), *n* being # of keywords and *m* being the length of your text.  That will NOT scale well.

Instead:

- Make `keywords` a `set`, not a `tuple`.  You only care about membership testing against `keywords`, and set membership tests are O(1).
- You need to tokenize `TEXT`.  This is a little more complicated than just doing `split()` since you need to handle removing punctuation/line breaks as well.
- Finally, iterate over your tokens using a "sliding window" iterator, in chunks of 3.  If the middle token is in your `keywords` set, grab the tokens around it and proceed.

That's it.  So, some pseudo-ish code:

```
keywords = {"banana", "apple", "orange", ...}
tokens = tokenize(TEXT)

for before, target, after in window(tokens, n=3):
    if target in keywords:
        #do stuff with `before` and `after`
```

Where `window` is your choice of sliding window implementations like those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator-in-python), and `tokenize` is either your own implementation involving `split` and `strip`, or perhaps `ntlk.tokenize` if you want a library solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
import re

alphabet = string.lowercase + string.uppercase
regex1 = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(keywords))
regex2 = re.compile("^(%s)" % "|".join(keywords))
regex3 = re.compile("(%s)$" % "|".join(keywords))

for match in regex1.finditer(TEXT):
    cut = TEXT[max(match.start() - before, 0) : match.end() + after]
    finalcut = cut
    if not regex2.search(cut):
        finalcut = finalcut.lstrip(alphabet)
    if not regex3.search(cut):
        finalcut = finalcut.rstrip(alphabet)
    print cut, finalcut
```

This can be further improved, since only twice the keyword can be at the beginning or at the end of the text, and thus shouldn't be removed.

```
cuts = [TEXT[max(match.start() - before, 0) : match.end() + after] for match in regex1.finditer(TEXT)]
finalcuts = [0] * len(cuts)
for i, cut in enumerate(cuts):
    if i == 0 and not regex2.search(cut):
        finalcuts[0] = cuts[0].lstrip(alphabet)
    elif i == 0:
        finalcuts[0] = cuts[0]
    if i == len(cuts) - 1 and not regex3.search(cut):
            if i == 0:
                finalcuts[i] = finalcuts[i].rstrip(alphabet)
            elif i > 0:
                finalcuts[i] = cuts[i].rstrip(alphabet)
    elif i > 0:
        finalcuts[i] = cuts[i].strip(alphabet)
print cuts, finalcuts
```