# Get next and previous item in dictionary using Python

Tags: python

I have an dictionary as follows:

```
defaultdict(None, {
    'Category 1': [
        {'id': 24, 'name': 'Video 1', 'cat_id': 16, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}, 
        {'id': 28, 'name': 'Video 5', 'cat_id': 16, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
    ], 
    'Category 3': [
        {'id': 25, 'name': 'Video 3', 'cat_id': 18, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}, 
        {'id': 29, 'name': 'Video 6', 'cat_id': 18, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
    ], 
    'Category 2': [
        {'id': 26, 'name': 'Video 2', 'cat_id': 17, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}, 
        {'id': 27, 'name': 'Video 4', 'cat_id': 17, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
    ]
})
```

And in my view I have next code:

```
video_id = int(request.POST.get('id', None))
cat_id = int(request.POST.get('cat_id', None))
cat_name = int(request.POST.get('cat_name', None))
tut_id = int(request.POST.get('tut_id', None))
```

I want to get **next** and **previous** item from the dictionary. If there are items onder same category get them, and if there are not, get the item from the next or previous category.

I have no idea how to start

**Expected output**

```
video_id = 3
cat_id = 18
cat_name = "Category 3"
tut_id = 14

next = {'id': 29, 'name': 'Video 6', 'cat_id': 18, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
prev = {'id': 28, 'name': 'Video 5', 'cat_id': 16, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: [Have a look at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035490/in-python-how-can-i-get-the-next-and-previous-keyvalue-of-a-particular-key-in/28035679)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, How can I get the next and previous key:value of a particular key in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035490/in-python-how-can-i-get-the-next-and-previous-keyvalue-of-a-particular-key-in)

Comment: What output are you expecting for a corresponding input?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you allowed to store the data in a different structure for easier access? Or does the data specifically have to be stored in this structure?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami It has to be in this structure.

Comment: Is the video id being fetched from the video name?

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultdict` can be flattened to a `list` of `dicts` like this. Assuming, you're using the latest version of python, a `dict` object maintains the order in which elements were inserted.

```
from pprint import pprint

d = defaultdict(None, {
    'Category 1': [
        {'id': 24, 'name': 'Video 1', 'cat_id': 16, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}, 
        {'id': 28, 'name': 'Video 5', 'cat_id': 16, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
    ], 
    'Category 3': [
        {'id': 25, 'name': 'Video 3', 'cat_id': 18, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}, 
        {'id': 29, 'name': 'Video 6', 'cat_id': 18, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
    ], 
    'Category 2': [
        {'id': 26, 'name': 'Video 2', 'cat_id': 17, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}, 
        {'id': 27, 'name': 'Video 4', 'cat_id': 17, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
    ]
})

dicts = []
for v in d.values():
    dicts.extend(v)

pprint(dicts)
```

Output:

```
[{'cat_id': 16, 'description': '', 'id': 24, 'name': 'Video 1', 'tut_id': 14},
 {'cat_id': 16, 'description': '', 'id': 28, 'name': 'Video 5', 'tut_id': 14},
 {'cat_id': 18, 'description': '', 'id': 25, 'name': 'Video 3', 'tut_id': 14},
 {'cat_id': 18, 'description': '', 'id': 29, 'name': 'Video 6', 'tut_id': 14},
 {'cat_id': 17, 'description': '', 'id': 26, 'name': 'Video 2', 'tut_id': 14},
 {'cat_id': 17, 'description': '', 'id': 27, 'name': 'Video 4', 'tut_id': 14}]
```

From what I inferred, the `category name` is not required in the output.
After reshaping the data in this format, the required data can be extracted using a for loop.

```
video_id = 3
cat_id = 18
cat_name = "Category 3"
tut_id = 14


idx = -1
found = False
while(idx < len(dicts)):
    idx += 1
    video_id_i = int(dicts[idx]['name'].split()[1])
    if video_id == video_id_i:
        found = True
        break

# TODO: check for index out of bounds
if found:
    prev = dicts[idx - 1]
    curr = dicts[idx]
    next = dicts[idx + 1]

    print(prev, curr, next, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
{'id': 28, 'name': 'Video 5', 'cat_id': 16, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
{'id': 25, 'name': 'Video 3', 'cat_id': 18, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
{'id': 29, 'name': 'Video 6', 'cat_id': 18, 'tut_id': 14, 'description': ''}
```