# Generic Association Measure for Ngrams using NLTK - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk, n-gram

In the nltk there are BigramAssocMeasures TrigramAssocMeasures, QuadgramAssocMeasures,

But if I have 5gram or 6gram, are there 5gramAssocMeasures o 6gramAssocMeasures in nltk?

Can someone help?

Comment: Take a look at [rolling/sliding window iterators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6822725/198633)

Comment: it is somthing different

Comment: The link is not specific to nltk, but works on any generic list. You could use that to generate n-grams, once you have a list of words, which nltk does give you

Comment: You can create them yourself by inheriting from `nltk.NgramAssocMeasures`.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget The question is not about generating n-grams (which can be easily achieved with `nltk.ngrams()`), but about a convenient "collection of {bi,tri,quad,...}gram association measures".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QuingramAssocMeasures in NLTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054764/quingramassocmeasures-in-nltk)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create them yourself.

Have a look at the source code of the `association` module.
You can find it under `<nltk>/metrics/association.py` (`<nltk>` stands for your NLTK path).

Start with

```
class QuingramAssocMeasures(NgramAssocMeasures):
    """
    A collection of 5-gram association measures.
    ...
    """
```

or whatever you like to call 5-grams.
Then you need to define the methods specific to the n-gram order, i.e. the ones that raise a `NotImplementedError` in the abstract class:
`._contingency()` and `._marginals()`.
You can peek at the implementations for 3- and 4-grams and build the methods by analogy. It's going to be a huge bulk of local variables though...

Comment: your class is very powerful!!

Comment: @gino If the answer helped you solve the problem, feel free to accept it.