# Sliding window in Python

Tags: python, sliding-window

I used the following famous code for my sliding window through the tokenised text document:

```
def window(fseq, window_size):
    "Sliding window"
    it = iter(fseq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, 0, window_size, round(window_size/4)))
    if len(result) == window_size:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        result_list = list(result)
        yield result_list
```

when I want to call my function with window size less than 6, everything is ok, but when I increase it, the beginning of the text is cut.

For example:

```
c=['A','B','C','D','E', 'F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
print(list(window(c, 4)))
print(list(window(c, 8)))
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],...

[['C', 'E', 'G', 'I'], ['E', 'G', 'I', 'J'], ['G', 'I', 'J', 'K'], ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L'], ['J', 'K', 'L', 'M']...
```

What's wrong? And why in the first output the first element is in round brackets?

My expected output for `print(list(window(c, 8)))` is:

```
[['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G','H'], ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M']...
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It differs materially from the solutions on [Rolling or sliding window iterator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6822725)

Comment: i've just added start point and te step according to islise documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

Comment: But *why*? You don't need a step  size. Leave it set to 1.

Comment: But i do need a particular step size, not just 1. It should depend on window size

Comment: Then you are not producing a 'famous sliding window' function. Start by explaining your usecase and your expected output. Your question is very unclear as it stands.

Comment: Question edited, thank you.

Comment: So you want to window to slide along a certain number of steps? Then you should not tinker with the initial window, you want to adjust the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version is incorrect. It adds a 4th argument (the step size) to the `islice()` function that limits how large the first slice taken is going to be:

```
result = tuple(islice(it, 0, window_size, round(window_size/4)))
```

For `4` or `5`, `round(window_size/4)` produces `1`, the default step size. But for larger values, this produces a step size that guarantees that values will be omitted from that first window, so the next test, `len(result) == window_size` is guaranteed to be false.

Remove that step size argument, and you'll get your first window back again. Also see [Rolling or sliding window iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator-in-python).

The first result is in 'round brackets' because it is a tuple. If you wanted a list instead, use `list()` rather than `tuple()` in your code.

If you wanted to have your window slide along in steps larger than 1, you should not alter the initial window. You need to add and remove `step` size elements from the window as you iterate along. That's easier done with a `while` loop:

```
def window_with_larger_step(fseq, window_size):
    """Sliding window

    The step size the window moves over increases with the size of the window.
    """
    it = iter(fseq)
    result = list(islice(it, 0, window_size))
    if len(result) == window_size:
        yield result
    step_size = max(1, int(round(window_size / 4)))  # no smaller than 1
    while True:
        new_elements = list(islice(it, step_size))
        if len(new_elements) < step_size:
            break
        result = result[step_size:] + list(islice(it, step_size))
        yield result
```

This adds `step_size` elements to the running result, removing `step_size` elements from the start to keep the window size even.

Demo:

```
>>> print(list(window_with_larger_step(c, 6)))
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'J'], ['E', 'F', 'I', 'J', 'M', 'N'], ['I', 'J', 'M', 'N', 'Q', 'R'], ['M', 'N', 'Q', 'R', 'U', 'V'], ['Q', 'R', 'U', 'V', 'Y', 'Z']]
>>> print(list(window_with_larger_step(c, 8)))
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'K', 'L'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'K', 'L', 'O', 'P'], ['G', 'H', 'K', 'L', 'O', 'P', 'S', 'T'], ['K', 'L', 'O', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'X'], ['O', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'X']]
>>> print(list(window_with_larger_step(c, 10)))
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'N', 'O', 'P'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'T', 'U', 'V'], ['J', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'Z']]
```