# Iterate over n successive elements of list (with overlapping)

Tags: python, list, iterator

The [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) python module implements some basic building blocks for iterators. As they say, "they form an iterator algebra". I was expecting, but I could not find a succinctly way of doing the following iteration using the module. Given a list of ordered real numbers, for example

```
a = [1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0]
```

... return a new list (or just iterate) grouping by some `n` value, say `2`

```
b = [(1.0,1.5),(1.5,2.0),(2.0,2.5),(2.5,3.0)]
```

The way I found of doing this was as follows. First split the list in two, with evens and odds indexes:

```
even, odds = a[::2], a[1::2]
```

Then construct the new list:

```
b = [(even, odd) for even, odd in zip(evens, odds)]
b = sorted(b + [(odd, even) for even, odd in zip(evens[1:], odds)])
```

In essence, it is similar to a moving mean.

**Is there a succinctly way of doing this (with or without itertools)?**

---

PS.:

**Application**

Imagine the `a` list as the set of timestamps of some events occurred during an experiment:

```
timestamp       event
47.8            1a
60.5            1b
67.4            2a
74.5            2b
78.5            1a
82.2            1b
89.5            2a
95.3            2b
101.7           1a
110.2           1b
121.9           2a
127.1           2b

...
```

This code is being used to segment those events in accord with different temporal windows. Right now I am interested in the data between `2` successive events; 'n > 2' would be used only for exploratory purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 2, you can just do

```
b = zip(a, a[1:])  # or list(zip(...)) on Python 3 if you really want a list
```

For fixed n, the technique is similar:

```
# n = 4
b = zip(a, a[1:], a[2:], a[3:])
```

For variable n, you could zip a variable number of slices, or (especially if the window size is close to the size of `a`) you could use slicing to take windows directly:

```
b = zip(*[a[i:] for i in xrange(n)])
# or
b = [tuple(a[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(len(a)-n+1)]
```

If `a` is not a list, you could generalize the `pairwise` recipe from the itertools docs:

```
import copy
import itertools

def nwise(iterable, n):
    # Make n tees at successive positions along the iterable.
    tees = list(itertools.tee(iterable, 1))
    for _ in xrange(n-1):
        tees.append(copy.copy(tees[-1]))
        next(tees[-1])

    return zip(*tees)
```

Comment: @glibdud: Ah, you're right. The single tee is still wrapped in a one-element tuple.

Comment: You second example should be `b = [tuple(a[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(len(a)-n+1)]`, unless I've overlooked something. It would seem that it is missing a `+1`.

Answer (score 12):

This is precisely what the [`pairwise` itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) is for, for `n=2` that is.

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> b = [1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0]
>>> list(pairwise(b))
[(1.0, 1.5), (1.5, 2.0), (2.0, 2.5), (2.5, 3.0)]
```

If you are looking for variable group sizes, see [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38151577/4686625) (I like the approach), or more generally you can implement a sliding window iterator and take slices [of which there are many approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator-in-python).

---

As an aside, a possibly poorly performing but amusing one-line window you could slice (*to control the overlap*) that isn't on the linked question would be this, using the new `yield from` syntax to combine generators.

```
from itertools import tee, islice
def roll_window(it, sz):
    yield from zip(*[islice(it, g, None) for g, it in enumerate(tee(it, sz))])
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> b = [1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5]
>>> list(islice(window(b, 3), None, None, 2))
[(1.0, 1.5, 2.0), (2.0, 2.5, 3.0), (3.0, 3.5, 4.0)]
```

Comment: Since Python 3.10, [Pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) is part of `itertools` module, implemented in C.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the [`pairwise` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) does overlapping pairs.

This recipe is also implemented in an external library, [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), among other helpful [windowing tools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#windowing):

```
import more_itertools as mit


a = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0]

list(mit.pairwise(a))
# [(1.0, 1.5), (1.5, 2.0), (2.0, 2.5), (2.5, 3.0)]

list(mit.windowed(a, n=2))
# [(1.0, 1.5), (1.5, 2.0), (2.0, 2.5), (2.5, 3.0)]

list(mit.stagger(a, offsets=(0, 1)))
# [(1.0, 1.5), (1.5, 2.0), (2.0, 2.5), (2.5, 3.0)]
```

Notice, with [`more_itertools.windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed), you can control `n`, the size of the sliding window (and even the amount of overlap via a `step` parameter if needed).  This tool may be useful in you exploration.

Install this library via `> pip install more_itertools`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator:

```
def groupListByN(lst, n):
  for i in range(len(a)-n+1):
    yield lst[i:i+n]

a = [1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0]
myDoubleList = [group for group in groupListByN(a, 2)]
myTripleList = [group for group in groupListByN(a, 3)]

print(myDoubleList)
print(myTripleList)
```

Result:

```
[[1.0, 1.5], [1.5, 2.0], [2.0, 2.5], [2.5, 3.0]]
[[1.0, 1.5, 2.0], [1.5, 2.0, 2.5], [2.0, 2.5, 3.0]]
```

I think this solution is pretty succinct

Answer (score 1):

Slice makes a copy of a sequence type so if you have a list of 1000 elements and the `n` is 3, `lst`, `lst[1:]` and `lst[2:]` puts  2997 (1000+999+998) items in memory.

Instead you can do it in more generic way for all iterables like:

```py
def n_wise(iterable, n=2):
    from collections import deque
    it = iter(iterable)

    try:
        d = deque([next(it) for _ in range(n)], maxlen=n)
        while True:
            yield tuple(d)
            d.append(next(it))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

This time only 1000 + n items are in memory at a time.

test:

```py
a = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
print(list(n_wise(a)))
print(list(n_wise(a, 3)))

# [(1.0, 1.5), (1.5, 2.0), (2.0, 2.5), (2.5, 3.0)]
# [(1.0, 1.5, 2.0), (1.5, 2.0, 2.5), (2.0, 2.5, 3.0)]
```