# Python - Storing values in multiple lists from a single string

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to store and update multiple lists at same time. My lists here a positions in a string, i.e. `<list-1>` will store the first position, `<list_0>` will store the middle position and `<list+1>` will store the last position in a three letter word. Since I'm using a rolling window, meaning that each list will store letters from multiple words in a sequence, it's really difficult to hard code everything, specially if the window length needs to be variable. 
Essentially, what I want is something like this `<for list0...listn>:<store/append character to list0 in string[0].....store/append character to listn in string s[n]>`
Here is my code:

```
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator-in-python
def window(iterable, size):
    iters = tee(iterable, size)
    for i in range(1, size):
        for each in iters[i:]:
            next(each, None)
    return zip(*iters)

        if(wordlength == 3):
            for each in window(temporary_string, wordlength):
                temp = ''.join(each) 
                k = temp[0]
                k = damino[k]
                p_1.append(k)
                t = temp[0]
                p_1w.append(t)
                k = temp[1]
                k = damino[k]
                p.append(k)
                t = temp[1]
                pw.append(t)
                k = temp[2]
                k = damino[k]
                p1.append(k)
                t = temp[2]
                p1w.append(t)
                word_list.append(temp)
```

For example, input string will be: ATGGAAE

Window size : 3

The output will be three arrays,

```
p-1|p|p+1
*|A|T
A|T|G
T|G|G
G|G|A
G|A|A
A|A|E
A|E|*
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?

Comment: I think the `if` part should be outside the function definition?

Comment: There is nothing wrong specifically with my code, it's just I need to make it more efficient.

Comment: so what is your input string? Can you please add a sample input and expected output!

Comment: Added explanation, it's not that difficult to understand, just difficult to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it. Instead of manually writing and updating each index individually, I created a dataframe to split the word for me, and then store it. For a three letter word, it looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'p-1':dftemp['word_list'].str[0],'p':dftemp['word_list'].str[1],'p+1':dftemp['word_list'].str[2]})
```

While not the neatest solution, it works flawlessly.