# Sample x number of days from a data frame with multiple entries per day in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with multiple time indexed entries per day. I want to sample and x number of days (eg 2 days) and the iterate forward 1 day to the end of the range of days. How can I achieve this.

For example if each day has greater than one entry:

```
 datetime             value
 2015-12-02 12:02:35    1
 2015-12-02 12:02:44    2
 2015-12-03 12:39:05    4
 2015-12-03 12:39:12    7
 2015-12-04 14:27:41    2
 2015-12-04 14:27:45    8
 2015-12-07 09:52:58    3
 2015-12-07 13:52:15    5
 2015-12-07 13:52:21    9
```

I would like to iterate through taking two day samples at a time eg

```
 2015-12-02 12:02:35    1
 2015-12-02 12:02:44    2
 2015-12-03 12:39:05    4
 2015-12-03 12:39:12    7
```

then

```
 2015-12-03 12:39:05    4
 2015-12-03 12:39:12    7
 2015-12-04 14:27:41    2
 2015-12-04 14:27:45    8
```

ending with

```
 2015-12-04 14:27:41    2
 2015-12-04 14:27:45    8
 2015-12-07 09:52:58    3
 2015-12-07 13:52:15    5
 2015-12-07 13:52:21    9
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/2901002
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result


dfs = [df[df['datetime'].dt.day.isin(x)] for x in window(df['datetime'].dt.day.unique())]
print (dfs[0])
             datetime  value
0 2015-12-02 12:02:35      1
1 2015-12-02 12:02:44      2
2 2015-12-03 12:39:05      4
3 2015-12-03 12:39:12      7

print (dfs[1])
             datetime  value
2 2015-12-03 12:39:05      4
3 2015-12-03 12:39:12      7
4 2015-12-04 14:27:41      2
5 2015-12-04 14:27:45      8
```

Comment: Thanks I get what you are doing here. Thanks. Can I assume you could use the deque implementation aswell?

Comment: Yes, it is another solution. In pandas is used `rolling`, but it aggregate data, so it is a bit problematic used here.

Comment: Jezrael I am geting issues with a dataset which spans several years. I get all the days which are adjacent eg 02, 03 for every month and year

Comment: is there a way to this with date instead of day?

Comment: You need change `day` to `date` only `dfs = [df[df['datetime'].dt.date.isin(x)] for x in window(df['datetime'].dt.date.unique())]`