# How to find where a specific sequence of numbers in a list starts?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, list, sequences

I couldn't find an answer for this, I'm a novice programmer so sorry about this dumb question!

Say in python I want to find **where** the first time the sequence [69, 69] appears in the list `[34,34,34,50,39,69,69,54]`. Is there a list notation for this? I feel like there is, but I haven't been able to find it. I'm not looking to make a function, I want to learn list/for methods.

so if `a = [34,34,34,50,39,69,69,54]` how would I find where `[69,69]` starts? (as a general statement) If I assume that `[69,69]` is in fact in `a`?

Comment: You might want to have a [sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/6779307) of width 2 and then check if that is equal to your target list

Comment: If you don't care about performance: `int(",".join(map(str, [34,34,34,50,39,69,69,54])).index("69,69") / 3)`

Comment: If you only need to deal numbers in the range 0-255, here's a cute shortcut that should be super-fast:  `bytes(L).index(bytes(s))`

Comment: Don't believe this is an exact duplicate of an existing question - this question is simpler than the one suggested.  Here's my solution: `list(zip(x, x[1:])).index((69,69))`.  If a is `[69,69]` then this would work: `list(zip(x, x[1:])).index(tuple(a))`

Comment: By means of explanation for my answer above: The solution zips the list together with the same list minus the first element.  This produces a list with pairs containing (i and i+1) positions.  Convert this to a list, then search for the pair in question `(69,69)`

Answer (score -1):

```
[x for x in enumerate(a) if x[1] == 69]
```

Comment: I don't believe this answers the OP's question.  The OP asked how to find **where** the 69,69 sequence started.