# Pandas: Split a dataframe rows and re-arrange column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Board': ['A', 'B'], 'Off': ['C', 'D'], 'Stops': ['Q/W/E', 'Z'], 'Pax': [10, 100]})
```

which looks like:

```
    Board   Off  Pax    Stops
0   A       C    10     Q/W/E
1   B       D    100    Z
```

I want to have a `DataFrame` split by `Stops` column and re-arranged as `Board` and `Off` in rows with `Pax` value being duplicated as follows;

```
    Board   Off  Pax
0   A       Q    10
1   Q       W    10
2   W       E    10
3   E       C    10
4   B       Z    100
5   Z       D    100
```

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import islice
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/2901002
#added a for return Pax
def window(a, seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield (*result, a)
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield (*result, a)

#join all columns 
a = df['Board'] + '/' + df['Stops'] + '/' + df['Off']
#split to lists
a = a.str.split('/')

#apply window function to each value and flatten
L = [(j,k,l) for x, y in zip(a, df['Pax']) for j,k,l in list(window(y, x, 2)) ]
print (L)
[('A', 'Q', 10), ('Q', 'W', 10), ('W', 'E', 10), 
 ('E', 'C', 10), ('B', 'Z', 100), ('Z', 'D', 100)]

#DataFrame constructor
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Board','Off','Pax'])
print (df)
  Board Off  Pax
0     A   Q   10
1     Q   W   10
2     W   E   10
3     E   C   10
4     B   Z  100
5     Z   D  100
```

**Timings**:

```
import pandas as pd
N = 1000
L1 = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
L = ['Q/W/E','Q1/W1/E1','Z','A/B/C/D']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Board': np.random.choice(L1, N), 
                    'Off': np.random.choice(L1, N), 
                    'Stops': np.random.choice(L, N), 
                    'Pax': np.random.randint(100, size=N)})
print (df)

def bharath(df):
    df['New'] = (df['Board']+'/'+df['Stops']+'/'+df['Off']).str.split('/')
    temp = df['New'].apply(lambda x : list(zip(x,x[1:])))
    di = {0 : 'Board',1:'Off'}
    return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i,index=np.repeat(j,len(i))) for (i,j) in zip(temp,df['Pax'].values)]).reset_index().rename(columns=di)


def jez(df):
    from itertools import islice
    #https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/2901002
    #added a for return Pax
    def window(a, seq, n=2):
        "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
        "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
        it = iter(seq)
        result = tuple(islice(it, n))
        if len(result) == n:
            yield (*result, a)
        for elem in it:
            result = result[1:] + (elem,)
            yield (*result, a)

    a = df['Board'] + '/' + df['Stops'] + '/' + df['Off']
    a = a.str.split('/')
    L = [(j,k,l) for x, y in zip(a, df['Pax']) for j,k,l in list(window(y, x, 2)) ]
    return pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Board','Off','Pax'])

def wen(df):
    df['New']=df[['Board','Stops','Off']].apply(lambda x : '/'.join(x),1)
    df['New2']= df['New'].str.split('/').apply(lambda x : list(zip(x[:-1],x[1:])))
    namedict = {0 : 'Board',1:'Off'}
    return df[['Pax','New2']].set_index('Pax').New2.apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index().drop('level_1',1).rename(columns=namedict)



print (jez(df))
#print (bharath(df))
print (wen(df))
```

---

```
In [433]: %timeit (jez(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.6 ms per loop

In [434]: %timeit (wen(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 747 ms per loop

In [450]: %timeit (bharath(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 406 ms per loop
```

Comment: This one is new for me yeild is still bit unfamiliar for me :)

Comment: Sir can you check now, It was problem thrown by keys need to figure out why, maybe because of so many duplicate index

Comment: I add your solution to timings.

Answer (score 4):

I break down the steps

```
df['New']=df[['Board','Stops','Off']].apply(lambda x : '/'.join(x),1)
df['New2']=df['New'].str.split('/').apply(lambda x : list(zip(x[:-1],x[1:])))

namedict = {0 : 'Board',1:'Off'}
df[['Pax','New2']].set_index('Pax').New2.apply(pd.Series).\ 
       stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index().\
             drop('level_1',1).rename(columns=namedict)
Out[1260]: 
   Pax Board Off
0   10     A   Q
1   10     Q   W
2   10     W   E
3   10     E   C
4  100     B   Z
5  100     Z   D
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach by using split and `pd.concat`, tuples will be converted to sereis when used `pd.DataFrame`

```
#Split the  by `/`
df['New'] = (df['Board']+'/'+df['Stops']+'/'+df['Off']).str.split('/')
#0    [A, Q, W, E, C]
#1          [B, Z, D]
#Name: New, dtype: object

temp = df['New'].apply(lambda x : list(zip(x,x[1:])))

# Zip will lead to output given (1,2,3) -> [(1,2),(2,3)]
#0    [(A, Q), (Q, W), (W, E), (E, C)]
#1                    [(B, Z), (Z, D)]
#Name: New, dtype: object

di = {0 : 'Board',1:'Off','index':'Pax'}
# Concat each row by converting it to DataFrame with key as Pax and rename the columns. 

ndf = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i,index=np.repeat(j,len(i))) for (i,j) in zip(temp,df['Pax'].values)])\
     .reset_index().rename(columns=di)
```

Output :

```
  Pax Board Off
0   10     A   Q
1   10     Q   W
2   10     W   E
3   10     E   C
0  100     B   Z
1  100     Z   D
```

Comment: Was in sucha a hurry to undelete, I thought you were coming

Comment: Check my sample data, `wen` solution working nice, but your return error :(

Comment: Even I want to search where the error is coming from but it is working on sample data

Answer (score 1):

Relatively more readable and somewhat efficient:

```
def expand_rows(series):
    """
    expand a row by splitting on "/"
    """
    return series.str.split("/", expand=True).stack()

d = {'Board': lambda dff: dff['Board'] + '/' + dff['Stops'],
     'Off': lambda dff: dff['Stops'] + '/' + dff['Off']
    }

df.set_index('Pax').assign(**d)[['Board', 'Off']].apply(expand_rows).reset_index(level=0)
```

Timed with the dataset from @jezrael's post, it yields the following:

> 15.8 ms ± 146 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)