# subtraction of time in two different lines in a text file using python

Tags: python, time, extract

I am working on some data extraction in a text file. I have been using MATLAB for a while now, but it seems kinda more stressful. I started using python for the extraction.  Now I have a pretty complex question and I don't even have any idea about how to do it.

Here's what I've done so far.
I have a log file that looks likes this:

```
2017-12-21T23:59:19.120Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.120Z 'D|Beat:2143|B->'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.120Z 'D|Beat:2113|sndB:0x5caa'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'I|PSnd:  61|snd[3D]:FFFF m:0x5caa e:0'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x5caa e:0'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|Beat:1259|WDTimeout: 300'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|Beat:1282|sd:0x5caa: e:0'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|Beat:1302|sprts'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|LgPl:  68|BSP:getSize:19'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|Beat:5503|GetPckt:0x4e5e'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|Beat:7140|Prtns->'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|Beat:2008|sevt:72'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'I|Beat:2021|SndQ:1'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|Beat:1805|snd:0x4e5e'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'I|PSnd:  61|snd[B0]:FFFF m:0x4e5e e:0'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[B0]m:0x4e5e e:0'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|Beat:1866|sd:0x4e5e:0'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.175Z 'D|Beat:1192|drop:2402 q:43'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.301Z 'D|Beat:1220|Rcv<-RP, s:2402'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.301Z 'D|LgPl:  68|BSP:getSize:19'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.301Z 'I|Beat:1243|RcvQ:1'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.301Z 'D|Beat:1245|FrMsg:0x4cc0 QMsg:0x3ba4'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.301Z 'D|Beat:8934|AAltB->B1302'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.416Z 'D|Beat:1192|drop:2402 q:50'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.416Z 'D|Beat:10392|RStp'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.437Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.489Z 'D|Beat:6502|slt:2'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.489Z 'D|Beat:10341|RStrt'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.489Z 'D|Beat:4713|prtTS:2'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.489Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.552Z 'D|Beat:1192|drop:2402 q:36'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.820Z 'D|Beat:1192|drop:2402 q:48'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.820Z 'D|Beat:10747|PLife:67'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.820Z 'D|Beat:4906|nojump'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.820Z 'D|Beat:10392|RStp'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.820Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:19.873Z 'D|Beat:6502|slt:3'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.266Z 'D|Beat:6502|slt:4'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.266Z 'D|Beat:10341|RStrt'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.266Z 'D|Beat:4713|prtTS:4'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.266Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.318Z 'D|Beat:1192|drop:2301 q:49'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.339Z 'D|Beat:1358|drop:2301 q:49'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.339Z 'D|Beat:1220|Rcv<-RP, s:2402'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.339Z 'D|LgPl:  68|BSP:getSize:19'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.339Z 'I|Beat:1243|RcvQ:1'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.339Z 'D|Beat:1245|FrMsg:0x4192 QMsg:0x4cc0'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.339Z 'D|Beat:1192|drop:2402 q:48'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.454Z 'D|Beat:1192|drop:2402 q:51'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.579Z 'D|Beat:1192|drop:2402 q:48'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.610Z 'D|Beat:10747|PLife:68'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.610Z 'D|Beat:4906|nojump'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.610Z 'D|Beat:10392|RStp'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.610Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:20.632Z 'D|Beat:6502|slt:5'
2017-12-21T23:59:21.045Z 'D|Beat:6502|slt:6'
2017-12-21T23:59:21.045Z 'D|Beat:10341|RStrt'
2017-12-21T23:59:21.045Z 'D|Beat:4713|prtTS:6'
2017-12-21T23:59:21.045Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
```

Now I need to extract out any line that contains `RStrtD` followed by another line having `RStpD` and then find the difference in the time between them, for every case of this in the text file, and then add the times together.
I extracted using the code below:

```
print" trying out something spectacular"

def get_line(file_name, find_word1, find_word2):

    lines = []
    for line in file_name.strip().split('\n'):
        if find_word1 in line:
            lines.append(line)
        elif find_word2 in line:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            pass
    return lines

def get_all_lines(f_name, find_word1, find_word2):

    f_content = open(f_name, 'r').read()
    return get_line(f_content,find_word1, find_word2)

def get_files_in (in_file, find_word1,find_word2, out_file):

    filtererd_lines = get_all_lines(in_file, find_word1, find_word2)
    joinliens = '\n'.join(filtererd_lines)
    open(out_file, 'w').write(joinliens)

#fix= "mm", "cts"
get_files_in("./sss1.txt", "RStrtD", "RStpD", "./result1.txt")
```

After running this, I received the following output:

```
2017-12-21T23:59:43.561Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:44.419Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:44.715Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:46.730Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:47.062Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:48.273Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:48.625Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:49.487Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:49.783Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:51.789Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:52.122Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:53.334Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:53.680Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:54.529Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:54.835Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
2017-12-21T23:59:56.840Z 'D|Beat: 971|RStrtD'
2017-12-21T23:59:57.182Z 'D|Beat: 997|RStpD'
```

This is good, but I now need to subtract the times from each other on each line and then take the sum of all of these differences. I really don't know how iI can go about this. I'm not yet familier with time vectors in python.

Comment: You should use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the times into `datetime` objects.

Comment: But the time striptime  is for subtracting two time, what if i need to subtract time from the second row from the first row, and 4th from 3rd and so on...then add them alll together.

Comment: Your first step should be to get a list of `datetime` objects.  Then use that list to generate the pairs of sequential times ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)).  Then you can use subtraction to produce `timedelta` objects.

Answer (score 0):

for doing math with time, I would recommend [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Its documentation is comprehensive and you can easily subtract time by just `time2-time1` which will give you a time delta.