# subtraction of previous time value from the next time value in python

Tags: python, datetime, data-extraction

I got this time array and I need to subtract the previous value from the next value. Like line 1-line 2 and line 3- line 4. I have been battling with this for days now, the problem now is how I will make the subtraction.

Here is the data:

```
2017-12-21T14:49:17.518Z
2017-12-21T14:50:49.723Z
2017-12-21T14:50:54.028Z
2017-12-21T14:50:54.343Z
2017-12-21T14:50:59.084Z
2017-12-21T14:50:59.399Z
2017-12-21T14:51:04.142Z
2017-12-21T14:51:04.457Z
2017-12-21T14:51:09.204Z
2017-12-21T14:51:09.521Z
2017-12-21T14:51:14.261Z
2017-12-21T14:51:14.579Z
2017-12-21T14:51:19.326Z
2017-12-21T14:51:19.635Z
2017-12-21T14:51:24.376Z
2017-12-21T14:51:24.691Z
2017-12-21T14:51:29.435Z
2017-12-21T14:51:29.750Z
2017-12-21T14:51:34.498Z
2017-12-21T14:51:34.813Z
```

I need to subtract the second from first, third from fourth, fifth from the sixth, and so on. Then get the result together in anther array and add them together.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Do you have any code that you can share? Are these strings or datetime objects?

Comment: They are datetime object... It's a long question actually, this is just the last part.  this is what i have tried so far [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654970/subtraction-of-time-in-two-different-lines-in-a-text-file-using-python)

Comment: If they are datetime objects then you can just subtract them. What's your desired output?

Comment: maybe in seconds, but i want to subtract line 1 from line 2, line 3 from 4 and so on. Can you help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with the `datetime` library and the [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function:

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654970/subtraction-of-time-in-two-different-lines-in-a-text-file-using-python), it seems like your times are a list of strings.

```
times = [
    '2017-12-21T14:49:17.518Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:49.723Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:54.028Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:54.343Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:59.084Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:59.399Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:04.142Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:04.457Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:09.204Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:09.521Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:14.261Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:14.579Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:19.326Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:19.635Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:24.376Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:24.691Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:29.435Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:29.750Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:34.498Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:34.813Z'
]
```

Convert them to datetime objects using `strptime`.The [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function applies a function to each element in an iterable.

```
times_converted = map(
    lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'), 
    times
)
```

The second argument to `strptime` above is the [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), which defines how the conversion should happen.

Now you can subtract consecutive times and use the `total_seconds()` method of [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to get the difference as desired:

```
diffs = [
    (b-a).total_seconds() for a, b in zip(times_converted[::2], times_converted[1::2])
]
#[92.205, 0.315, 0.315, 0.315, 0.317, 0.318, 0.309, 0.315, 0.315, 0.315]
```

I used [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to get pairs of times from the list to subtract. The notation `[::2]` means take every other item in the list, starting at index 0. Likewise `[1::2]` means take every other item in the list, starting at index 1. More on python's slice notation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).

If you're not comfortable with list comprehensions and `zip()`, the above code can also be written as single `for` loop:

```
diffs = []
for i in range(0,len(times), 2):
    diffs.append((times_converted[i+1]-times_converted[i]).total_seconds())
```

**More on `zip()`**

The `zip()` function takes two iterables and returns pairs of tuples. For instance, consider the following example:

```
# suppose you had two lists
X = ['A', 'B', 'C']
Y = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
print(zip(X, Y))
#[('A', 'X'), ('B', 'Y'), ('C', 'Z')]
```

So essentially it takes one item from the first list and one item from the second list and returns this as a tuple.

Comment: in my last answer, i later extracted just the time out using spilt function. thanks alot. please can you recommend where i can understand datetime well. am self learning and i haven't found except the python site.

Comment: @idrisbadmus Here is the [link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) for `datetime`. There are a lot of good examples on that page. Good luck.

Comment: @idrisbadmus Does this actually do what you want? You said you want second-first, fourth-third, etc, not also third-second. Also, it does look like they come in real pairs. Like you're doing some operation every five seconds and each time it takes about 0.3 seconds.

Comment: oh No, just checking well now.  @pault, i need it to subtract second-first , fourth-third. I thought that's whats it did, but this subtract second-first, third secoud, fourth- third.

Comment: @idrisbadmus I updated the code as you specified. The only change was in the `zip()` part - we are getting different pairs slices to subtract.

Comment: oh, you mean you still have the old answers right, and can you just help me past in the comment session, the former answer in the 'zip()'. i just want to learn the difference

Comment: I'll edit the post to add more explanation on the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way via [`dateutil.parser.parse`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse):

```
from dateutil import parser

lst = ['2017-12-21T14:49:17.518Z',
       '2017-12-21T14:50:49.723Z',
       '2017-12-21T14:50:54.028Z',
       '2017-12-21T14:50:54.343Z',
       '2017-12-21T14:50:59.084Z',
       '2017-12-21T14:50:59.399Z']

lst = list(map(parser.parse, lst))
changes = [(j-i) for i, j in zip(lst, lst[1:])][::2]
```

To convert this to seconds:

```
seconds = [i.total_seconds() for i in changes]
```

Comment: oh, i really don't know about this panda module, does it work on python 2.7 and can i used an imported text file instead of list>?

Comment: @idrisbadmus, i have updated with `dateutil` solution. yes, you can read a imported text file to a list in python.

Comment: oh, i just checked now that panda wasn't in my win 2.7 version . Thanks though, yeah i can import text to list, just wanted to know if it was possible with panda. Thank again

Comment: `parser.parse` is much cleaner than `strptime(...)`. Is `dateutil` a standard package now?

Comment: @pault, not yet but it should be, i'll add a link in my post.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis can you help with subtracting first from second , 3rd from fourth, and so on. Thats where i am actually stuck since,

Comment: but these are the changes between consecutive times, right? `changes = [(j-i) for i, j in zip(lst, lst[1:])]`

Comment: @jp_data_analysis You include third minus second.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, in that case you can ignore every second result from `changes`? i'll update accordingly.