# Looping over a list

Tags: python, list

I have difficulty understanding how should I solve the following problem.

I would like to sum every "n" elements in a list in the consecutive order. For example:

```
n = 2
seq = [2, 2, 1, 3]
res = [4, 3, 4]
```

How can I apply certain condition (such as a sum) on every n elements of a list? I do not want to import any special libraries because it will help me to understand the basics.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very many ways to produce a sliding window sum. For instance:

```
winsize = 2
inputs = [2, 2, 1, 3]

method1 = [sum(inputs[start:start+winsize])
           for start in range(0, len(inputs)-winsize+1)]

method2 = []
accumulator = 0
for i,v in enumerate(inputs):
    accumulator += v
    if i >= winsize:
        accumulator -= inputs[i-winsize]
    if i >= winsize-1:
        method2.append(accumulator)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a while loop to iterate through the list. First create a variable `i`, 
which is 1 less than the `n`, then go through the while loop, incremented `i` while it is less than `len(seq)` (which in this case is 4). Each time, add the item at the current index (`i`) in the list and the preceding `n` items.

```
n = 2
seq = [2, 2, 1, 3]
res = []

i = n-1

while i < len(seq):
    res.append(sum(seq[i - (n-1):i+1]))
    i += 1
```

Then `print(res)` will output `[4, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Why are you using `while` instead of `for i in range(n-1,len(seq))`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `map` and `zip`:

```
In [9]: def summer(seq, le):
   ...:     return map(sum, zip(*[seq[i:] for i in range(le)]))
   ...: 

In [10]: 

In [10]: list(summer(seq, 2))
Out[10]: [4, 3, 4]

In [11]: list(summer(seq, 3))
Out[11]: [5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> n = 2
>>> seq = [2, 2, 1, 3]
>>> res = []
>>> for i in range(len(seq) - n + 1):
...     res.append(sum(seq[i:i+n]))
... 
>>> res
[4, 3, 4]
```

This does the work - just loop through the elements upto `len(seq) - n + 1` - this is because you don't want python to sum the last numbers which are less than `n` in length.