# Generate all possible sequential strings from list using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
["toaster", "oven", "door"]
```

I need to get ALL the possible sequential words that can be created.  The output should look like this:

```
["toaster", "toaster oven", "toaster oven door", "oven", "oven door", "door"]
```

What is the most efficient way to get this list? I've looked at `itertools.combinations()` and a few other suggestions found on Stack Overflow, but nothing that would produce this exact result.

For example, the above list is not a powerset, because only *words adjacent to each other in the input list* should be used. A powerset would combine `toaster` and `door` into `toaster door`, but those two words are not adjacent.

Comment: what about single `'door'`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov  thanks just corrected. "door" would be needed as well

Comment: And `toaster door`?

Comment: @DeepSpace, I'm ONLY looking for strings in sequential order N+1

Comment: "Sequential words" is not a thing. What you want are called *substrings*, which are *subsequences* made of all consecutive elements from the initial sequence. So you want to generate all substrings of that sequence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
words = ["toaster", "oven", "door"]  

length = len(words)
out = []
for start in range(length):
    for end in range (start+1, length+1):
        out.append(' '.join(words[start:end]))

print(out)

# ['toaster', 'toaster oven', 'toaster oven door', 'oven', 'oven door', 'door']
```

You just need to determine the first and last word to use.

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
[' '.join(words[start:end]) for start in range(length) for end in range(start+1, length+1)]

#['toaster', 'toaster oven', 'toaster oven door', 'oven', 'oven door', 'door']
```

Comment: Note: you can use `for start in range(L-1)` with `L = len(words)` because: 1) using lowercase `l` is **evil** and 2) the OP does not want the empty string and you are doing an unneccessary iteration anyway.

Comment: Not sure why you range `start` all the way through to length + 1, you can safely remove the `+1` there. It's not a *problem* because `range(3, 3)` is empty, but you make Python do that extra step without reason.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: no, not `L-1`, then `start` ends at `1`, so you'd never get `door` on its own.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: and no to using `L` either. Just use `length`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to create [*sliding windows*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator) of increasing length, use the `window()` function from the top answer there inside a `range()` loop to increment the lengths:

```
from itertools import islice, chain

# window definition from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773

def increasing_slices(seq):
    seq = list(seq)
    return chain.from_iterable(window(seq, n=i) for i in range(1, len(seq) + 1))

for combo in increasing_slices(["toaster", "oven", "door"]):
    print(' '.join(combo))
```

This outputs:

```
toaster
oven
door
toaster oven
oven door
toaster oven door
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

a = ['toaster', 'over', 'door']

result = []
for i in [itertools.combinations(a, x + 1) for x in range(len(a))]:
    result += [' '.join(e) for e in list(i)]

print(result)
```

What do you think about this solution?
The result is:

```
['toaster', 'over', 'door', 'toaster over', 'toaster door', 'over door', 'toaster over door']
```

Comment: That includes non-sequential combos.