# Finding a sequence in list using another list In Python

Tags: python, list, comparison, comparison-operators

I have a `list = [0, 0, 7]` and I when I compare it against `anotherList = [0, 0, 7, 0]` using `in` it gives me `False`.

I would like to know how I can check if numbers in one list are in the same sequence as another list.

So, if I do `anotherList2 = [7, 0, 0, 0]`:

`list in anotherList2` returns False

But, `list in anotherList` return True

Comment: You shouldn't name lists `list`, it overrides a builtin name.  Also, `list in anotherList` will return False here, not True

Comment: In this case, `in`, checks if the list is an element of `anotherList`, not if the elements of `list` are contained in `anotherList`.  If you do `anotherList.append(list)` and then `list in anotherList`, you will see it returns True

Comment: Construct a sliding window iterator over the larger dataset, and see if any of those windows are equal to your first list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner function that will check if list `a` is in list `b`:

```
>>> def list_in(a, b):
...     return any(map(lambda x: b[x:x + len(a)] == a, range(len(b) - len(a) + 1)))
...
>>> a = [0, 0, 7]
>>> b = [1, 0, 0, 7, 3]
>>> c = [7, 0, 0, 0]
>>> list_in(a, b)
True
>>> list_in(a, c)
False
>>>
```

Comment: Can you explain the lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check each position in the list one by one.
start iterating through anotherList

if the first element of list is same as the current element in the anotherList start checking until you find the whole sequence

The program goes here:

```
def list_in(list,anotherList):
    for i in range(0,len(anotherList)):
        if(list[0]==anotherList[i]):
            if(len(anotherList[i:]) >= len(list)):
                c=0
                for j in range(0,len(list)):
                    if(list[j]==anotherList[j+i]):
                        c += 1
                        if(c==len(list)):
                            print("True")
                            return
                    else:
                        continue


    print("False")
    return
list = [0,0,7]
anotherList = [0,0,7,0]
anotherList2 = [7,0,0,0]

list_in(list,anotherList)
list_in(list,anotherList2)
```

Comment: This will give false positives when the lists contain numbers of multiple digits and the adjacent digits of two numbers in a list happen to match the those of two different numbers in the other list. For example, `[12, 3]` and `[1, 23]` will match using your method, which is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I have solved it by making a function and checking each number one by one

Answer (score 0):

Using slices it's pretty simple to write an efficient function that does what you're looking for:

```
def sequence_in(seq, target):
    for i in range(len(target) - len(seq) + 1):
        if seq == target[i:i+len(seq)]:
            return True
    return False
```

Which we can use like this:

```
sequence_in([0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: EDIT: to change the range length based on @blhsing's answer. still prefer this to the `any`/`map` so will leave here.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great answers here, but here's another way you could tackle it using strings as a medium.

```
def in_ist(l1, l2):
    return ''.join(str(x) for x in l1) in ''.join(str(y) for y in l2)
```

This basically turns the elements of the lists into strings and uses the `in` operator, which does what you'd expect in this case, checking whether `l1` is in `l2`.