# How to count occurrences of a list of string inside of a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example my list is

```
lst=['hello','world','this','is','hello','world','world','hello']
subString=['hello','world']
```

The result I'm looking for is in this case is 2 since the list ['hello','world'] occurs twice with that same order.

I tried doing

```
list(filter(lambda x : x in substring,lst))
```

but that returns all of hello and world

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/6779307

Comment: What if the array looks like this: `['hello', 'world', 'hello world', 'hello', 'world hello']`? The currently accepted answer falls apart if your goal is to ensure that two consecutive list items create the string `'hello world'`. It may work for the specific example you've provided but it is not a great general-purpose answer. The one I have provided accounts for such a scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `" ".join()` on both lists to create a string and then use `str.count()` to count the number of occurrences of `subString` in `lst`

```
lst=['hello','world','this','is','hello','world','world','hello']
subString=['hello','world']

l = " ".join(lst)
s = " ".join(subString)

count = l.count(s)
print("Joined list:", l)
print("Joined substring:", s)
print("occurrences:", count)
```

outputs:

```
Joined list: hello world this is hello world world hello
Joined substring: hello world
occurrences: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the elements into a list of lists and then filter by those that match your substring array.

---

```
joinedWords = [lst[n:n + len(subString)] for n in range(0, len(lst), len(subString))]
    # => [['hello', 'world'], ['this', 'is'], ['hello', 'world'], ['world', 'hello']]
filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x == subString, joinedWords))

print(len(filtered))  # 2
```

Comment: What if `sub_string` had more than 2 items?

Answer (score 0):

Since all elements are string in this case, I'd create a string from each list, then count the occurrences of the second string in the first string:

```
lst=['hello','world','this','is','hello','world','world','hello']
subString = ['hello','world']

s = ' '.join(lst)
subs = ' '.join(subString)

print(s.count(subs))
```

Comment: This will give you false positives if you have an array like `['hel', 'low', 'orld']`. You need to join with a space (in which case your answer would be exactly the same as the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `window` generator from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/6779307) and a `Counter`, this can be expressed as:

```
from collections import Counter

lst=['hello','world','this','is','hello','world','world','hello']
subString=('hello','world')

counts = Counter(window(lst, len(subString)))

print(counts[subString])
# 2
```

If you want to skip the `Counter`, you could do

```
print(sum(x == subString for x in window(lst, len(subString))))
```