# How to multiply all elements in a list with each other in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to multiply each element with the one next to it, and then sum them together. 
( I have to use a for/while loop since this is what is required for the question i am trying to solve)

```html
C= [7,5,4,5,3]
j = 0
for j in len(C):
    j += 1
    answ = (int(C[0::j])*int(C[1::j]))
print answ
```

I keep getting the error message "int object not iterable"
I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: what would be the desired outcome for the example list you provided?

Comment: you are iterating over ```len(C)``` which is a number you should write :
```for j in C``` instead.

Comment: the problem with your code is that you are trying to convert a list to int with `int(C[0::j])`. Do you understand how *slicing* works?

Comment: the outcome will be 90. and while i do understand the basics for slicing the program wasn't cooperation, so i started trying random things and this is what i ended up with.

Comment: You're looking for a [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator).  Using `window` from those answers, do `sum((x*y) for x, y in window(C))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of issues with your approach. First, you're attempting to iterate over the value `len(C)` in your for-loop. Instead, you'd want to use `range(len(C))` as this returns a generator of integers from 0 to `len(C)`, which you can iterate over. Second, we don't make changes to loop variables in Python because the variable is overwritten at the start of every iteration of the loop so any changes would be ignored. Third, your calculation of `answ` will yield errors because you're trying to cast array slices to integers. You're also indexing them backwards. What you want to do is:

```
sum(a * b for a, b in zip(C, C[1:]))
```

This will get you a sum of the multiplication of every element in the list with the element in the position to the right of it. This doesn't consider the edge of the list however.

Comment: @HebaMasarwa No problem

Answer (score 3):

You could `zip()` through list, multiplying items and taking `sum()` at the end:

```
C = [7,5,4,5,3]
print(sum(x * y for x, y in zip(C, C[1:])))
# 90
```

Comment: thank you so much! but if it isn't too much trouble can i ask you what exactly is zip? i am new to coding and i really want to understand the material better. sorry for your trouble!