# Python 3.x - Two Word Generator from a column in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a huge csv file that has a column with descriptions of user problems.  Something like 
1. "Please reset my password - User name is xxxx"
2. "My phone voicemail is not working"
3. "I have a broken desk"

I am trying to create a generator in python that reads this column and creates a generator with two words.  So, in the above example, it should create a generator like this:
('Please reset', 'reset my', 'my password', 'password -',....
 'My phone', 'phone voicemail',...
 'I have', 'have a'....)

Note that I am looking to create only generators, not lists, because the file is huge.
I can create a generator with the words ('Please', 'reset', 'my', 'password'...), but I am not able to concatenate words.

I am using:
**word   = (word for row in csv.reader(f) for word in row[3].lower().split())** to create the generator with words.

Comment: How do you want the generator to behave around the end of lines?  for example with the lines `a b c` and `d e f`, should the output include `c d`?

Comment: Can you please update you post with a .csv file sample?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh it should not include c d

Answer (score 0):

```
listofwords = [words[i]+" "+words[i+1] for i in range(len(words)-1)]
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, one or two sentences about what's going on will prove helpful to your readers.

Comment: That's a list not a generator.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [Rolling or sliding window iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator).  The accepted answer to that question is the one below, though I suggest reading through the answers there:

```
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result
```

So for every line, we can get the window iterator over that line, then use `chain` to flatten them into a single iterator.

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

with open('file.txt') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    descriptions = (line[3].lower().split() for line in r)
    iterators = map(window, descriptions)
    final = chain.from_iterable(iterators)
    for item in final:
        print(item)
```

For the file

```
,,,a b c
,,,d e f
```

this would print

```
('a', 'b')
('b', 'c')
('d', 'e')
('e', 'f')
```