# How best way to transform one list into new list with pairs of elements from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My problem was to transform the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` to `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]`.

I resolved it with:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

result = [[e, a[idx + 1]] for idx, e in enumerate(a) if idx + 1 != len(a)]
```

What the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]

res = list(zip(L, L[1:]))
```

This gives a list of tuples. If a list *of lists* is a strict requirement, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
res = list(map(list, zip(L, L[1:])))

print(res)

[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

For a generalised solution to your problem, see [Rolling or sliding window iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the "best" way, but here is another way.

```
d = [1,2,3,4,5]

results = [[d[i], d[i+1]] for i in range(len(d) - 1)]
print(results)
# OUTPUT
# [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```