# How to split a list into groups of 4 where first elements are greater than the last?

Tags: python, list

I have this list of integers that I want to split into groups of 4 elements by condition:

```
result = [0, 4, 10, 6, 15, 9, 18, 35, 40, -30, -90, 99]
```

The first item of each group should be greater than the fourth following item.
Output should be like this:

```
[[10, 6, 15, 9], [18, 35, 40, -30], [35, 40, -30, -90]]
```

but how do I apply that conditions in this code?

```
split_no = 4
list(split_list(result, split_no))
```

Currently my output looks like this:

```
[[0, 4, 10, 6], [15, 9, 18, 35], [40, -30, -90, 99]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
arr1 = [0, 4, 10, 6, 15, 9, 18, 35, 40, -30, -90, 99]
arr2=[arr1[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(arr1)) if len(arr1[x:x+4])==4]
for each in arr2[:]:
    if each[0]<=each[3]:
        arr2.remove(each)
```

Now, if you try printing out arr2;

```
print(arr2)
```

you get:

```
[[10, 6, 15, 9], [18, 35, 40, -30], [35, 40, -30, -90]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a list of all the sub-list of length 4 is created, using [Python's list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
input_list = [0, 4, 10, 6, 15, 9, 18, 35, 40, -30, -90, 99]

all_sublists = [input_list[i:i+4] for i in range(len(input_list)-3)]

print(all_sublists)
# [[0, 4, 10, 6], [4, 10, 6, 15], [10, 6, 15, 9], [6, 15, 9, 18], [15, 9, 18, 35], [9, 18, 35, 40], [18, 35, 40, -30], [35, 40, -30, -90], [40, -30, -90, 99]]
```

Then, the sub-lists are filtered using the wanted conditions:

```
output = [sublist for sublist in all_sublists if sublist[0]>sublist[-1]]

print(output)
# [[10, 6, 15, 9], [18, 35, 40, -30], [35, 40, -30, -90]]
```

The one-line solution could be:

```
output = [input_list[i:i+4] for i in range(len(input_list)-3)
          if input_list[i]>input_list[i+3]]

print(output)
# [[10, 6, 15, 9], [18, 35, 40, -30], [35, 40, -30, -90]]
```

Comment: Thanks !  can you explain , use of => range(Len(input_list)-3)

Comment: @VinayChaudhari We want to iterate over the indexes, instead of the elements of the list. `range(n)` gives an iterator over `n` integer starting from 0. In order to get all the sub-lists of length 4, we have to iterate over the `n = len(input_list)-3` first elements.

Answer (score 0):

Answers from [xdze2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54418134/7851470) and [gireesh4manu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417585/7851470) have a drawback of keeping all subsequences of length 4 in memory. We can avoid that by using a [rolling window iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator).

For example, taking one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54110047) and improving it a bit:

```
from itertools import islice, tee

def windows(iterable, size): 
    iterators = tee(iterable, size) 
    iterators = [islice(iterator, i, None) for i, iterator in enumerate(iterators)]  
    yield from map(list, zip(*iterators))

def is_valid(seq):
    return seq[0] > seq[-1]

result = [0, 4, 10, 6, 15, 9, 18, 35, 40, -30, -90, 99]
print(list(filter(is_valid, windows(result, 4))))
```

will give you:

```
[[10, 6, 15, 9], [18, 35, 40, -30], [35, 40, -30, -90]]
```