# Python. How to read file with a step (blocks) and not re-write each block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, nlp

What is the best way to solve my problem?

I have a file that contains string lines.
I want to analyze it. So in my approach I need to take first *N* lines, do something with them, than instead 1-st line I need to take *N+1* line and analyze this block, than instead 2-nd line - *N+2* line and so on to the end of the file.

```
st_1
st_2
st_3
...
st_LAST
```

**First block:**

```
[st_1, st_2, ... , st_N]
```

**Second block:**

```
[st_2, st_3, ... , st_N, st_N+1]
```

**Last Block:**

```
[st_LAST-N, st_LAST-N+1, ... , st_LAST]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider you've assigned the text of the file to a variable (s). Next, you can split it by lines. Loop through the range of length and use it to create slices and loop them though.

```
s='some text1\nsome text2\nsome text3\nsome text4\nsome text5\nsome text6\n'
n_block = 3 # size of the block you want to split
list_s=s.split('\n')
for i in range(len(list_s)):
    block = i + n_block if i + n_block < len(list_s)-1 else len(list_s)-1
    for y in list_s[i:block]:
        #...
        #do something
        #...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
filename = "your_file.txt"
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

N = 5# size of block

for i in range(len(lines)-N+1):
    print(lines[i:i+block_size])
```