# How to split a list up

Tags: python

I have a list that I called lst, it is as follows:

```
lst = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G']
```

What i want to know is how to split this up into four letter strings which start with the first, second, third, and fourth letters; then move to the second, third, fourth and fifth letters and so on and then add it to a new list to be compared to a main list.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to make the first four letter string?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a "sliding/rolling window", and might be able to achieve the first part of what you're looking for from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator . I'm not sure what is meant by needing to compare the new list to the old list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you mean you want the output `["ACTG", "CTGA", "TGAC", "GACG", "ACGC", "CGCA", "GCAG"]` from your example input? Will you always want four-letter strings, or could the desired strings have a different length? Also, what have  you tried, and just where are you stuck?

Comment: @RoryDaulton yes that's what i am trying to get as my output.  I am new to Python and basically trying to learn on the fly.  I really am not sure what to try.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or a Tutorial. ... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

To get the first sublist, use `lst[0:4]`. Use python's `join` function to merge it into a single string. Use a for loop to get all the sublists.

```
sequences = []
sequence_size = 4
lst = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G']

for i in range(len(lst) - sequence_size + 1):
    sequence = ''.join(lst[i : i + sequence_size])
    sequences.append(sequence)

print(sequences)
```

Answer (score 0):

All 4-grams (without padding):

```
# window size:
ws = 4
lst2 = [
    ''.join(lst[i:i+ws])
    for i in range(0, len(lst))
    if len(lst[i:i+ws]) == 4
]
```

Non-overlapping 4-grams:

```
lst3 = [
    ''.join(lst[i:i+ws])
    for i in range(0, len(lst), ws)
    if len(lst[i:i+ws]) == 4
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
lst = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G']
i=0
New_list=[]
while i<(len(lst)-3):
    New_list.append(lst[i]+lst[i+1]+lst[i+2]+lst[i+3])
    i+=1
print(New_list)
```

> Output:

```
['ACTG', 'CTGA', 'TGAC', 'GACG', 'ACGC', 'CGCA', 'GCAG']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers solve your problem, but if you are looking for a *pythonic* way to do this, I used *List comprehension*. It is very recommended to use this for code simplicity, although sometimes diminish code readability. Also it is quite shorter.

```
lst = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G']
result = [''.join(lst[i:i+4]) for i in range(len(lst)-3)]
print(result)
```