# How to print tuples in succession in ascending order (1,2,3),(2,3,4).....(10,11,12) using comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a question where it asks me to print 10 elements consisting of 3 tuples `(1,2,3)(2,3,4)....(10,11,12)` using comprehension.

So far I've been able to print it in one long tuple `(1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6....)` with commas and no brackets separating them. The hint on the question is that only 1 for-part inside this comprehension is needed.

**Input**:

```
def try2():
  e = [x+a for x in range(0,10) for a in range (1,4)] 
  print (tuple(e))

try2()
```

**Output:**

> (1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7,6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9,
>   10, 9, 10, 11, 10, 11, 12)

**Expected:**

> (0,1,2),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)......(10,11,12)

**Actual:**

> (1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7,6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9,
>   10, 9, 10, 11, 10, 11, 12)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the inner `range` generator to the `tuple` constructor instead:

```
[tuple(range(x, x + 3)) for x in range(1, 11)]
```

This returns:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10), (9, 10, 11), (10, 11, 12)]
```