# Calculate list of distances

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
my_list = [A,B,G,X,F,D]
```

Each letter on the list is some point in space (x,y).

I have a function to calculate distance between 2 points:

```
dist = distance(A,B)
```

I need to calculate list of distances between neighbouring points on the list:

```
list_of_distances = [distance(A,B), distance(B,G), distance(G,X), distance(X,F), distance(F,D)]
```

The question is: 
How to do it iteratively in most pythonic way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator). Using a standard sliding window, you can simply compute `[distance(a, b) for a,b in windows(my_list, 2)]`

Comment: `dist = [distance(my_list[i], mylist[i+1]) for i in range(len(my_list)-1)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use `zip` built-in function:

```
dist = [distance(a, b) for a, b in zip(my_list, my_list[1:])]
```

or as suggested by @DaniMesejo:

```
 dist = list(map(distance, my_list, my_list[1:]))
```

Comment: map can receive multiple iterables, so you can do map(distance, my_list, my_list[1:])

Comment: yes, you will mind if I add this in my answer?

Comment: Go ahead, is fine with me

Answer (score 2):

Just another way: `[*map(distance, my_list, my_list[1:])]`

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]
>>> def distance(a, b):
        return abs(a - b)

>>> [*map(distance, my_list, my_list[1:])]
[2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```