# Is there a list method in Python to access the next and/or previous value of a list item?

Tags: python, list

As I asked, is there a method or easy way to access the next and previous value from a list in a for?

```
for foo in reversed(values):
    print(foo)
    print(foo) # NEXT ONE
    print(foo) # PREVIOUS ONE
```

Comment: Use a while loop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6822725/3001761

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)

Comment: There are various approaches possible… you could create a `zip(r_values, r_values[1:])` to iterate over two offset values at once (or more if you need). Alternatively `enumerate(r_values)` to also get the index, and access other indices from the list.

Comment: @deceze Hey there, I'd like to do the subtraction between foo[n] and foo[n-1], for the whole values for the list. How could I do that with zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List does not have methods to retrieve previous and/or next value of a list item. However, you can write some code to achieve this.

Let's say you have a list of top five imaginary warriors:
`warriors = ['Sam', 'Preso', 'Misus', 'Oreo', 'Zak']` and you want to find the previous and next warrior for each of the warrior in the list.

You can write some code (Note: You need Python >= 3.6)

**Code**

```py
warriors = ['Sam', 'Preso', 'Misus', 'Oreo', 'Zak']

for i, warrior in enumerate(warriors):
  print(f'Current: {warrior}')
  print(f'Previous: {warriors[i-1] if i>0 else ""}')
  print(f'Next: {warriors[i+1] if i<len(warriors)-1 else ""}')
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @deceze talked about using zip for this one as well, I wonder if would you be so kind as to show me an example with zip?

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve the same result with the same list using zip, as @deceze mentioned in a comment. However, if you are satisfied with the answer I provided, you can accept it. Thanks.