# How to change a sliding window generator to jump two elements at a time?

Tags: python

I've reproduced the sliding window code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/15382800), but I need to modify it to jump two elements at a time instead of just one.

Original code:

```
def window(seq, n=3):
    it= iter(seq)
    result = list(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + [elem,]
        yield result
```

If I start with the following list:

```
My_List= ['adl_01_11', 'adl_01_12', 'adl_01_13', 'adl_01_14', 'adl_02_15', 'adl_02_16', 'adl_02_17', 'adl_02_18', 'adl_02_19', 'adl_02_20', 'adl_02_21', 'adl_02_22']
```

and I apply the window over `My_List`, I get the following result:

```
[['adl_01_11', 'adl_01_12', 'adl_01_13'], ['adl_01_12', 'adl_01_13', 'adl_01_14'], ['adl_01_13', 'adl_01_14', 'adl_02_15'], ['adl_01_14', 'adl_02_15', 'adl_02_16'], ['adl_02_15', 'adl_02_16', 'adl_02_17'], ['adl_02_16', 'adl_02_17', 'adl_02_18'], ['adl_02_17', 'adl_02_18', 'adl_02_19'], ['adl_02_18', 'adl_02_19', 'adl_02_20'], ['adl_02_19', 'adl_02_20', 'adl_02_21'], ['adl_02_20', 'adl_02_21', 'adl_02_22']]
```

How do I change this function if I want to iterate through 2 items at a time?
That means I expect a result like this:

```
[['adl_01_11', 'adl_01_12', 'adl_01_13'], ['adl_01_13', 'adl_01_14', 'adl_01_15'], ['adl_01_15', 'adl_01_16', 'adl_02_17'], ['adl_01_17', 'adl_02_18', 'adl_02_19'], ['adl_02_19', 'adl_02_20', 'adl_02_21']]
```

Notice that `adl_02_22` is no longer in the results, and my window iterates every 2 items.

In the window function I tried changing `result[1:]` to `result[2:]` but it doesn't work well.
Any idea?

Comment: is using `yield` necessary?

Comment: Maybe `result = result[2:] + [elem, next(it)]`, with a try catch to catch the `StopIteration` exception if there is an element left-over? It's not sure elegant, though. It might be best to unroll the inner `for`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)

Comment: @dantiston That's where OP found the code they asked to modify, so clearly, no! That answer rolls one item at a time, OP wants modify the code to roll two items at a time.

Comment: @QQ1821 Please look at my updated solution for a more general answer, since I had first hard-coded the window size at exactly 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I propose three solutions for this problem:

1. a specific one for a window of size 3 with a step of 2,
2. a general one with any window and step size,
3. skip all this and use existing libraries.

### Solution 1: sliding window with hard-coded size=3 and step=2

If you replace the `for elem in it:` loop by the equivalent `while True:` loop which tries `next(it)` until `StopIteration` is raised, that will let you use `next(it)` twice per iteration instead of just once:

```py
def window_size3_step2(seq):
    it = iter(seq)

    try:
        result = [0,0,next(it)]
    except StopIteration:
        return

    while True:
        try:
            result = [result[2], next(it), next(it)]
        except StopIteration:
            break
        else:
            yield result


My_List= ['adl_01_11', 'adl_01_12', 'adl_01_13', 'adl_01_14', 'adl_02_15', 'adl_02_16', 'adl_02_17', 'adl_02_18', 'adl_02_19', 'adl_02_20', 'adl_02_21', 'adl_02_22']

print(f"{list(window_size3_step2(My_List))}")
```

Output:

```
[['adl_01_11', 'adl_01_12', 'adl_01_13'], ['adl_01_13', 'adl_01_14', 'adl_02_15'], ['adl_02_15', 'adl_02_16', 'adl_02_17'], ['adl_02_17', 'adl_02_18', 'adl_02_19'], ['adl_02_19', 'adl_02_20', 'adl_02_21']]
```

Testing for shorter lists:

```py
for n in range(7):
    print(f"len={n} result={list(window_size3_step2(range(n)))}")

len=0 result=[]
len=1 result=[]
len=2 result=[]
len=3 result=[[0, 1, 2]]
len=4 result=[[0, 1, 2]]
len=5 result=[[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4]]
len=6 result=[[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4]]
```

### Solution 2: general window function with arbitrary size and step

This second solution goes back to using `islice` to take into account the given window size argument, which I've renamed `size` for clarify, and accepts a `step`  argument that can also take any positive integer value.

```py
from itertools import islice
def window(seq, size=3, step=1):
    if size < 1 or step < 1:
        raise ValueError("Nobody likes infinite loops.")
    it = iter(seq)
    result = list(islice(it, size))
    while len(result) == size:
        yield result
        if step >= size:
            result = list(islice(it, step-size, step))
        else:
            result = result[step:] + list(islice(it, step))
```

On your input list, `window(My_List, size=3, step=2)`, or just `window(My_List, step=2)`, returns the list of lists you want.

I've also tested this with a wide variety of seq length, size and step, and I can confirm it works correctly in all cases. E.g., the output of this loop (try it yourself, I don't want to paste this long output here) is correct on every line:

```py
for input_size in range(10):
    for window_size in range(1,4):
        for step_size in range(1,4):
            print(f"len={input_size} size={window_size} step={step_size} "
                  f"result={list(window(range(input_size), size=window_size, step=step_size))}")
```

### Solution 3: there's a library for this!

The [more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed) library already provides a function doing just this:

I had to install it first:

```sh
pip3 install more_itertools
```

Use it:

```py
from more_itertools import windowed
print(f"{list(windowed(My_List, 3, step=2))}")

[('adl_01_11', 'adl_01_12', 'adl_01_13'), ('adl_01_13', 'adl_01_14', 'adl_02_15'), ('adl_02_15', 'adl_02_16', 'adl_02_17'), ('adl_02_17', 'adl_02_18', 'adl_02_19'), ('adl_02_19', 'adl_02_20', 'adl_02_21'), ('adl_02_21', 'adl_02_22', None)]
```

It's not exactly what you asked for, though, because it pads the last incomplete window with `None` (or any fill value you provide) instead of truncating the end.

While using existing libraries is often a good choice, I learned more creating solutions 1 and 2, and I hope you find value in the progression.

### Credits:

I found the more_itertools solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412374/3216427

Comment: Your output does not match the expected output that the OP posted.

Comment: Sorry @Kapocsi I cannot see the difference. Can you pinpoint it for me and I'll adjust my answer as needed?

Comment: I think the OP transcribed his expected result incorrectly: your_output[1][2] != op_expected_output[1][2], your_output[2][0] != op_expected_output[2][0], your_output[2][1] != op_expected_output[2][1], your_output[3][0] != op_expected_output[3][0]

Comment: Thank you @Kapocsi I see what you mean, now. I will assume each instance of `adl_01_15` in the expected output was meant to be `adl_02_15`, since that's what was in the input list.

Comment: NP. It looks like `adl_01_15`, `adl_01_16`, and `adl_01_17` are not in the original list.

Comment: @joanis Indeed, I did an error and take the wrong list but anyway thanks a lot for your time and your answer, that's exactly what I needed

Comment: I just read through all the answers in the question you started with, and I noticed that one of the answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412374/3216427) mentions `more_itertools.windowed` (https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed), which does exactly what I did, but with more features supported.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have transcribed your expected output incorrectly.

The items in your expected output, (`adl_01_15`, `adl_01_16`, `adl_01_17`), do not exist in `My_List`.

If so, this will do:

```py
islice(window(My_List), 0, None, 2)
```

and if you don't need a generator:

```py
list(window(My_List))[::2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# input
lst = ['adl_01_11', 'adl_01_12', 'adl_01_13', 'adl_01_14', 'adl_02_15', 'adl_02_16', 'adl_02_17', 'adl_02_18', 'adl_02_19', 'adl_02_20', 'adl_02_21', 'adl_02_22']
# remove last entry if required
lst = lst[:-(len(lst[1:]) % 2)]
# get midpoints of sublist and add previous and following value to it
lst = [[lst[i-1], x, lst[i+1]] for i, x in enumerate(lst) if ((i+1) % 2) == 0]

print(lst)
# [['adl_01_11', 'adl_01_12', 'adl_01_13'],
#  ['adl_01_13', 'adl_01_14', 'adl_02_15'],
#  ['adl_02_15', 'adl_02_16', 'adl_02_17'],
#  ['adl_02_17', 'adl_02_18', 'adl_02_19'],
#  ['adl_02_19', 'adl_02_20', 'adl_02_21']]
```