# How to sum up elements in list in a moving range

Tags: python, sum, range, indices

I'm trying to sum up elements from list in a moving range. For instance, when the user input a customized range 'n', list[0] to list[n] will be added up and stored in a new list, followed by list[1] to list[n+1] until the end. Finally the maximum number in the new list will print out. However, in my code, it seems that the elements are continuously summing up.
Thanks a lot for your help.

The list is:

```
[5.8, 1.2, 5.8, 1.0, 6.9, 0.8, 6.0, 18.4, 18.6, 1.0, 0.8, 6.4, 12.2, 18.2, 1.4, 6.8, 41.8, 3.6, 5.2, 5.2, 4.6, 8.6, 16.6, 13.2, 9.6, 41.6, 37.2, 110.0, 30.0, 34.8, 24.6, 7.0, 13.4, 0.5, 37.0, 18.8, 20.4, 0.6, 6.4, 2.4, 1.0, 7.6, 6.6, 4.4, 2.4, 0.6, 3.2, 21.2, 28.2, 3.2, 2.4, 14.4, 0.6, 1.6, 4.4, 0.8, 0.6, 1.6, 1.0, 27.0, 52.6, 10.2, 1.0, 4.2]
```

My code:

```
days = int(input('Enter customized range: '))
n = np.arange(days) 
total = 0
count = 1
max_total = []



while (count + len(n) - 2) <= (len(rain_b) - 1):

    for i in range(count+len(n)-4, count+len(n)-2):
        total += rain_c[i]
    #print(rain_b[count+number-1])
    #total = sum([(rain_c(count+number-4)) : (count+number-2)])
        max_total.append(total)
    count += 1
    print(max_total)
```

Comment: Can you also include the desired and actual output for that input, or, if that's not possible, for a smaller example? Also, include the variables rain_b and rain_c so we can replicate your code.

Comment: You need to explain what each variable in your code represents. python doesn't require declaration of variables but it's still good practice.

Comment: Take a look at [Rolling or sliding window iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this (`lst` being your list and `n` being your range):

```
print(max(sum(lst[i:i+n+1]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)))
```

So for example:

```
>>> lst = [5.8, 1.2, 5.8, 1.0, 6.9, 0.8, 6.0, 18.4]
>>> n = 5
>>> print([sum(lst[i:i+n+1]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)])
[21.5, 21.7, 38.9]
>>> print(max(sum(lst[i:i+n+1]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)))
38.9
```

Comment: I don't think this is helpful for a beginner.

Comment: @Drew You're right sorry. Well, my answer is not difficult at all, it's a basic list comprehension. You're free to write something more long if you wish :) I like one liners

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using numpy, you can use `np.convolve()` with an array of ones with length `n`:

```py
>>> n = 5
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> np.max(np.convolve(x, np.ones(n, dtype=x.dtype), mode="valid"))
35
```

This has the effect of performing the dot product of `np.ones(n)` with each `n`-element "window" of the array `x`. The `sliding_window_view()` from `numpy.lib.stride_tricks` is analogous and helps explain:

```py
>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> windows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x, n)
>>> windows
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> windows.sum(axis=1)
array([10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35])
>>> np.convolve(x, np.ones(n, dtype=x.dtype), mode="valid")
array([10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35])
```

Answer (score -1):

1. I would clean up your loop conditionals to be more clear and idiomatic.
2. I believe the problem is that you're not zeroing **total** out between iterations.
3. What are rain_b and rain_c? There should only be 1 input list and 1 output list.
4. Why not store n as an integer instead of some object? I don't have numpy on my pc so I just removed that part.

Here's psudo code of how I would do this:

```
For x in range 0 up to len(input_list) - n:
     window_total = 0
     for y in range x to x+n-1:
         window_total += input_list[y]
     output_list.append(window_total)
```

Comment: Linux user? It's "pseudo", in this context, not "sudo" :D

Comment: Lol, you're correct I have been working on a linux problem for weeks.. fixed

Answer (score -1):

Based on an iterator/array containing cumulative sum of numbers, you can get the rolling sum of n values by subtracting the cumulative values that are n positions behind.  This approach has an O(N) time complexity (as opposed to computing the sum of every subrange, which is O(N x W) where W is the rolling window size)

**Without numpy:**

```
L = [5.8, 1.2, 5.8, 1.0, 6.9, 0.8, 6.0, 18.4, 18.6, 1.0, 0.8, 6.4, 12.2, 18.2, 1.4, 6.8, 41.8, 3.6, 5.2, 5.2, 4.6, 8.6, 16.6, 13.2, 9.6, 41.6, 37.2, 110.0, 30.0, 34.8, 24.6, 7.0, 13.4, 0.5, 37.0, 18.8, 20.4, 0.6, 6.4, 2.4, 1.0, 7.6, 6.6, 4.4, 2.4, 0.6, 3.2, 21.2, 28.2, 3.2, 2.4, 14.4, 0.6, 1.6, 4.4, 0.8, 0.6, 1.6, 1.0, 27.0, 52.6, 10.2, 1.0, 4.2]

n = 3

from itertools import accumulate

S = (a-b for a,b in zip(accumulate(L),accumulate([0]*n+L)))
print(max(S)) # 188.8
```

**Using numpy**

```
import numpy as np

L = np.array([5.8, 1.2, 5.8, 1.0, 6.9, 0.8, 6.0, 18.4, 18.6, 1.0, 0.8, 6.4, 12.2, 18.2, 1.4, 6.8, 41.8, 3.6, 5.2, 5.2, 4.6, 8.6, 16.6, 13.2, 9.6, 41.6, 37.2, 110.0, 30.0, 34.8, 24.6, 7.0, 13.4, 0.5, 37.0, 18.8, 20.4, 0.6, 6.4, 2.4, 1.0, 7.6, 6.6, 4.4, 2.4, 0.6, 3.2, 21.2, 28.2, 3.2, 2.4, 14.4, 0.6, 1.6, 4.4, 0.8, 0.6, 1.6, 1.0, 27.0, 52.6, 10.2, 1.0, 4.2])

n = 3

S = np.cumsum(L)
S[n:] -= S[:-n]
print(np.max(S)) # 188.8
```