# Generate all size n combinations of consecutive elements in a list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, combinations, combinatorics

I would like to devise an algorithm that generates all combinations of five consecutive elements from a list of integers. For example:

```
Set -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Subset 1 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Subset 2 -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Subset 3 -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: These are just subsequnces of adjacent elements of size n. You can create that with a sliding window. This is evident from your example data. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get number of iterations from ( length of list - size + 1 )
2. Create new list for each iteration.

Implementation in Python using list slicing:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
size = 5

num_iterations = len(lst) - size + 1

for i in range(0, num_iterations):
    print(lst[i:size + i])
```