# Create a sublist from a list. First with second, second with third, etc

Tags: python, list

From this

```
a = ['foo','bar','cat','dog']
```

to create another variable `b` that will have it as follows:

```
b = [['foo','bar'],['bar','cat'],['cat','dog']] # with this order
```

I have tried this:

```
b = [[i] * 2 for i in a]
```

but gives this:

```
[['foo', 'foo'], ['bar', 'bar'], ['cat', 'cat'], ['dog', 'dog']]
```

No external libraries please.

Comment: `[[a[i], a[i+1]] for i in range(len(a)-1)]`

Comment: `b = [[a[i], a[i+1]] for i in range(len(a)-1)]`

Comment: I suggest googling "python sliding window" to find the solution for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like you attempted to, you just need a slight modification to account for different spots in the list:

```
b = [[a[i-1], a[i]] for i in range(1, len(a))]
```

Output:

```
[['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'cat'], ['cat', 'dog']]
```

Since you want to pair "touching" items the `a[i-1]` and `a[i]` accomplish this. Then just loop through each `i` in `len(a)`. We use `range(1,len(a))` instead of `range(len(a))`, however, because we don't want to pair the first value of `a` with something before it because it is the first value.

An arguably cleaner solution would be to use `zip`, but it depends on preference:

```
b = [list(i) for i in zip(a, a[1:])]
```

In this case we use `a[1:]` in order to offset that list so that the pairs are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = ['foo','bar','cat','dog']
b = [x for x in zip(a, a[1:])]
```