# Finding CDRs (sequence) by its definition

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I am puzzling to find the CDRs by its definition. Definition is to be matched with the previous and next sequence pattern (known as prefix and suffix respectively) and the CDR is between them. Moreover few point mutation are allowed in  prefix and suffix patterns.
To make it clear I will explain it with the example.

Lets say we have a **sequence**= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLCDEFEFGHIJMGHIJMCDEFGHNOPQRSTUCDEFGHVWXYZ'.

**CDR1 Definition:->** from 3rd  position after prefix to starting of suffix

**prefix pattern**='ABCDEFGHI' with max 3 point mutation but 'D' is important at '3rd' position ie allowed prefix could be ABC**D**EFHHI, BBC**D**EFGHI etc

**Suffix pattern**='GHIJMCDEF' with max 3 point mutation but 'D' is important at '7th' position ie allowed prefix could be GJJJMC**D**EF, GHAAMC**D**CF etc

**CDR2 Definition:->** prefix to 3 positions before to suffix

**prefix pattern**='DEFGHNOP' with 3 mutation but 'G' is important at '4th' position

**Suffix pattern**='WXYZ' with 3 mutation but 'X' is important at '2nd' position

So by the definition,
Highlighted sequence is the CDR1 in the sequence:-  ABCDEFGHIJKL**CDEFEFGHIJM**GHIJMCDEF

and CDR2 will be:- ABCDEFGHIJKLCDEFEFGHIJMGHIJMCDEFGHNOP**QRSTUCDEF**GHVWXYZ

I tried a lot but could not come up with any solution.

What I tried one of them is below

```
import random

# Define variables
A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
B = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
C = []

# Iterate how ever many times, i.e. 10
for i in range(10):
    results = A
    swaps = random.randint(1, 3)
    swapA = random.sample(A, swaps)
    swapB = random.sample(B, swaps)
    
    # Group the swaps together, so we don't need to use an extra loop
    zipped = list(zip(swapA, swapB))

    # Replace numbers with letters
    for i in range(len(results)):
        # Check if this is the right place to swap
        for swap in zipped:
            if results[i] == swap[0]:
                # Swap the two numbers!
                results[i] = swap[1]

    # Add to results list
    C.append(results)

# View results!
print(C)
```

What I am thinking is to generate all the possible permutation and combination of CDR suffix and prefix, store them into a list. Then match all the generated sequence one by one but it is very time consuming. I have 1 million sequences to separate CDR1 and CDR2.

I know this is not a right way to do it but having no coding background I could not come up with any solution.

Is there any way I can find it easily?

Comment: It would also be a great idea if we can print some message ("CDR1 not found"), if desired pattern is not found (CDR)?

Comment: Instead of generating all possible mutations, it would be quicker to walk through the input sequence with a sliding window of the same size as the CDR pattern and compare its edit distance.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Thank you. I had also thought of the same but since I am new to coding I don't know how to write code for the slider. If you can help me in this, Please help me out by guiding me

Comment: this might get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator