# Python - limit iteration per loop, but go through the whole loop in next iterations

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to limit number of elements that will be executed through one loop iteration, but after that, I need to continue from the point where loop stopped, and re-run the loop, until all the elements are processed through multiple loop iterations..

Let's say I have a list:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and static limiter:

```
limit = 4
```

so in this case I want to add only 4 elements from the list (1,2,3,4) into some other list and do some kind of processing and parsing, and after that I want to add next 4 elements (5,6,7,8), and do the processing, and at the end the rest of the elements (9,10).

My current code only process the first 4 elements.
I used `islice` for this.

```
from itertools import islice

list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
new_list=[]
limit = 4
for item in islice(list1, limit):
    new_list.append(item)
print (new_list)
```

So, the desired output is to have `new_list` printed first only with elements `[1,2,3,4]`, after that list is being reset and populated with elements `[5,6,7,8]` and at the end list is reset with elements `[9,10]`. Solution should not involve dealing with additional `new_lists` - only one new list object.

Number of elements in `list1` can be less than a `limit` value.

Note: I am using python2.7 (can't use python 3 on the customer server).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will require two nested loops, most likely.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks - that can be acceptable solution, can you give us hints

Comment: `for i in range(0, len(list1), 4): new_list = list1[i:i + 4]` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
new_list = []
limit = 4
for item in list1:
    new_list.append(item)
    if len(new_list) == limit:
        print(new_list)
        new_list = []
print(new_list)
```

Essentially, the loop will add entries to `new_list`, and when there are `limit` entries in `new_list`, `new_list` is emptied.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:
This code initially makes a deep copy of your original list, then the while loop process the list in steps delimited for the number defined in the `limit`. So in this case it will take 4 elements "do something" (in this case is just poping the elements from the list). When the range is less than the limit it will just take the last elements.

```
import copy

list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list2 = copy.deepcopy(list1)

new_list=[]
limit = 4
counter = 0

while list2:
    try:
        for i in range(0, limit):
            removed_element = list2.pop()
            new_list.append(removed_element)
        print("cicle finished")
    except:
        for i in list2:
            removed_element = list2.pop()
            new_list.append(removed_element)
        print("last cicle")
```