# How to group a list into inclusive sequential n-tuples

Tags: python, list, grouping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python)

I have a list like this:

```
list = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
```

How can I group this to get the following Python output

```
[(A,B), (B,C), (C, D), (D,E), (E,F), (F,G)]
```

So the values are grouped by the secound value but the order is preserved...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `zip()`:

```
zip(lst, lst[1:])
```

Also, you shouldn't use the name `list`, as you will override the built-in list type.

Example:

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
>>> zip(lst, lst[1:])
[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'F'), ('F', 'G')]
```

For a version that will work with generators or other one-pass iterables, you can use the [pairwise recipe from the itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Comment: This is the best way I think.

Comment: how is this better than the other 2? .... that are the same ... (+1 all the same its the right answer)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> zip(a, a[1:])
<zip object at 0x7fe6e905ab90>
>>> list(zip(a, a[1:]))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

use a list comprehension that iterates from 0 to length - 1

```
print [(a[i],a[i+1]) for i in range(len(a)-1)]
```

or even better , just use zip

```
print zip (a,a[1:])
```