# Get a list of tuples of neighbors

Tags: python, list, tuples

What is a simple way to use `zip` to do:

```
Input: (1,2,3,4,5)
Output: ((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5))
```

Edit: yes, general ngram solutions are similar, but too verbose for such a simple task. See answers below to see why.

Comment: What's your *current* way of doing it?

Comment: Another related post [Quick implementation of character n-grams using python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18658106/4099593)

Comment: The ngram solutions are obviously super-solutions to this but some of the implementations are string-specific and none are as simple as below.

Comment: It's a dupe of many questions including http://stackoverflow.com/q/13167881/2301450

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zip` the tuple with its own tail:

```
>>> ł = (1,2,3,4,5)
>>> zip(ł, ł[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: You're gonna need an explicit cast to a tuple or list.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking/hoping for. Absolutely elegant. Yes, to strictly satisfy the question it must be cast as a tuple.

Comment: @zephyr Not in Python2

Comment: Do not call variable `l`, this may be confused with `1`.

Comment: @BhargavRao As `zip()` return a list in Python 2 while OP is asking for tuple, I think it should cast it anyway.

Comment: The actual return value of `zip` (whether a list or a generator) isn't that interesting; it's trivial to adapt to another sequence if necessary.

Comment: Ah ah, `ł` is pretty but it breaks in Python 2 as unicode cannot be used as variable name. `lst` is juste fine, no need of one-letter. ;)

Comment: My change in variable name is somewhat tongue-in-cheek, and only works in Python 3. But yes, lower-case `l` is a bad variable name :)

Comment: Python **ZIP** function is more faster then Python **Generator Expression or List Comprehension**. You can check running below Code. I have provide small example too. **python -mtimeit -s't = (1,2,3,5)' 'x=zip(t, t[1:])' = "1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.32 usec per loop "** AND **python -mtimeit -s't = (1,2,3,5)' 'x=tuple((t[i], t[i+1]) for i in range(len(t)-1))' = 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 usec per loop**

Comment: @LavanyaPant: Well, you _should_ expect `zip` to be faster because it does its looping at C speed, which is much faster than a Python `for` loop, even one inside a list comp or generator expression.

Comment: @Lavanya: you're testing a generator expression, not a list comprehension.

Comment: Yes Eugene your right. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize the tuple using a list comprehension or generator expression:

```
>>> x = (1, 2, 3 4, 5)
>>> tuple((x[i], x[i+1]) for i in range(len(x)-1))
((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5))
```

Or using slicing:

```
>>> tuple(x[i:i+2] for i in range(len(x)-1))
((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5))
```

Comment: Slicing can also be used with `x[i:i + 2]` instead of `(x[i], x[i + 1])`

Answer (score 0):

```
in = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
out = tuple([(in[i], in[i+1] for i in range(len(in) - 1)])
print(out)

>> ((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility

```
x = (1,2,3,4,5)
tuple([(a,b) for a,b in zip(x[:-1],x[1:])])
```

Comment: You do realise the list comp is meaningless right?  `tuple(zip(x[:-1],x[1:]))` is just fine.

Comment: @StevenSummers I do now.