# Is there a need for range(len(a))?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

One frequently finds expressions of this type in python questions on SO. Either for just accessing all items of the iterable

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i])
```

Which is just a clumbersome way of writing:

```
for e in a:
    print(e)
```

Or for assigning to elements of the iterable:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = a[i] * 2
```

Which should be the same as:

```
for i, e in enumerate(a):
     a[i] = e * 2
# Or if it isn't too expensive to create a new iterable
a = [e * 2 for e in a]
```

Or for filtering over the indices:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i % 2 == 1: continue
    print(a[i])
```

Which could be expressed like this:

```
for e in a [::2]:
    print(e)
```

Or when you just need the length of the list, and not its content:

```
for _ in range(len(a)):
    doSomethingUnrelatedToA()
```

Which could be:

```
for _ in a:
    doSomethingUnrelatedToA()
```

**In python we have `enumerate`, slicing, `filter`, `sorted`, etc... As python `for` constructs are intended to iterate over iterables and not only ranges of integers, are there real-world use-cases where you need `in range(len(a))`?**

Comment: I think `range(len(a))` is usually people who are fairly inexperienced with Python (although not necessarily with programming in general).

Comment: I only used `range(len(a))` when I was learning Python.  Nowadays, I don't because, as you stated, it's quite easy to replace.

Comment: not really. I use `range(len(a))` often, because i don't need the content of list a, but only the length.

Comment: @aIKamili - That is one use of `range(len(a))`.  However, even that can be replaced by:  `for _ in a:`.  The code I gave will only iterate for as many times as there are items in list `a`.

Comment: @alKamili I'd personally use `enumerate` or `for _in list_` instead, but I guess in that case it is mostly just personal preference.

Comment: What if in the loop I need to access the element before and after the current one? I usually have `for i in range(len(a)): doSomethingAbout(a[i+1] - a[i])` How to get around that?

Comment: @Zhang18 I think your example gives an IndexError. If you have for example `a=range(10)` then your loops goes from `doSomethingAbout(a[1] - a[0])` to `doSomethingAbout(a[10] - a[9])` but there is no element `a[10]`. You can slice the list and then iterate over the sliced list:

`a = range(10)
for i in a[:-1]:
   print(a[i+1]-a[i])`

Comment: @JaakkoSeppälä agreed. I was just giving an example to illustrate the main issue of having to loop through indices, not just values, understanding there is a corner case at the end which is besides the main point.

Comment: Should be an use case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59112685/how-to-multiply-each-integer-one-by-one-and-display-result-in-progressive-ord

Comment: My suspicion: Old-fashioned tutorials are stupid and teach the `range(len(list))` solution when they should be using enumerate as the starting point! Just suffered through 30 mins of trying to explain the `range(len(list))` chorizo to someone I'm tutoring, just because that's what Codecademy decided to burden us with. Why??? Obscure excuses aside, the default should be `enumerate()` but `range(len(list))` persists. This standard makes PHP's `foreach()` look good, for goodness sake (^_^)

Comment: FWIW `enumerate()` was only added to Python in 2003 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/), 3 years after Python 2 came out and 12 years after the original release in 1991. I suspect that `range(len(list))` was the standard for so long that it's just hard to get rid of.

Answer (score 20):

If you need to work with indices of a sequence, then yes - you use it... eg for the equivalent of [numpy.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)...:

```
>>> a = [6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4]
>>> sorted(range(len(a)), key=a.__getitem__)
[2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 0]
```

Comment: OK, this looks sensible. Thank you very much. But the question is: what will you do with your newly sorted list of indices. If via this list again you access some iterable, the dog bites its own tail.

Comment: Equivalent to: `[ix for ix, _ in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda i: i[1])]` though, although yours is arguably nicer/geekier.

Answer (score 12):

**Short answer**: mathematically speaking, no, in practical terms, yes, for example for Intentional Programming.

Technically, the answer would be **"no, it's not needed"** because it's expressible using other constructs. But in practice, I use `for i in range(len(a)` (or `for _ in range(len(a))` if I don't need the index) to make it explicit that I want to iterate as many times as there are items in a sequence without needing to use the items in the sequence for anything.

So: *"Is there a need?"*? — yes, I *need* it to express the meaning/intent of the code for readability purposes.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentional_programming

And obviously, if there is no collection that is associated with the iteration at all, `for ... in range(len(N))` is the only option, so as to not resort to `i = 0; while i < N; i += 1 ...`

Comment: What advantages has `for _ in range(len(a))` over `for _ in a`?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: yeah, I just amended my answer a few seconds before your comment... so I guess the difference is whether you want to be really explicit about **"repeat AS MANY TIMES as there are items in `a`"** as opposed to **"for every element in `a`, regardless of the content of `a`"**... so just an Intentional Programming nuance.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I've included it in my question.

Comment: To get a list of `'hello'` with as many items as in list `a`, use `b = ['hello'] * len(a)`

Answer (score 11):

What if you need to access two elements of the list simultaneously?

```
for i in range(len(a[0:-1])):
    something_new[i] = a[i] * a[i+1]
```

You can use this, but it's probably less clear:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(a[0:-1]):
     something_new[i] = a[i] * a[i+1]
```

Personally I'm not 100% happy with either!

Comment: `for ix, i in enumerate(a)` seems to be equivalent, no?

Comment: One should use [pairwise](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.pairwise) instead.

Comment: In those situations I do: `for a1,a2 in zip(a[:-1],a[1:])`

Comment: zip is the preferred method. Please use zip.

Comment: @stidmatt Why would zip be the preferred method when it is much less readable?

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson `zip` is considerably more readable once you become familiar with the language, as brevity is one of the core tenets of Python. Happy coding!

Comment: @iteratedwalls I am very familiar with the language. I have two issues with `zip` here. First, the names `a1, a2` gives no indication that they're just offset by 1. `a[i], a[i+1]` makes this clear. Second, you have to reason through the list slices and figure out exactly what's getting combined and how--put a semicolon or negative in the wrong place and it means something else, generally nonsense. It's certainly cute, but it's not a common enough operation to be idiomatic. Calling it "the preferred method" suggests there's really no argument against it, which is just wrong depending on context

Comment: Please see: [How can I iterate over overlapping (current, next) pairs of values from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/)

Answer (score 2):

Going by the comments as well as personal experience, I say no, there is no *need* for `range(len(a))`.  Everything you can do with `range(len(a))` can be done in another (usually far more efficient) way.

You gave many examples in your post, so I won't repeat them here.  Instead, I will give an example for those who say "What if I want just the length of `a`, not the items?".  This is one of the only times you might consider using `range(len(a))`.  However, even this can be done like so:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for _ in a:
...     print True
...
True
True
True
True
>>>
```

Clements answer (as shown by Allik) can also be reworked to remove `range(len(a))`:

```
>>> a = [6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4]
>>> sorted(range(len(a)), key=a.__getitem__)
[2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 0]
>>> # Note however that, in this case, range(len(a)) is more efficient.
>>> [x for x, _ in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda i: i[1])]
[2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 0]
>>>
```

So, in conclusion, `range(len(a))` is not *needed*.   Its only upside is readability (its intention is clear).  But that is just preference and code style.

Comment: Thank you very much. And then again, readability is (partially) in the eye of the beholder. I interpret `for _ in a:` as "Iterate over a but ignore its content", but I interpret `for _ in range(len(a))` as "Get the length of a, then create a number of integers of the same length, and then finally ignore the content".

Comment: @Hyperboreus - Very true.  It's just code style.  My goal was to show there will never be a "I must use `range(len(a))` or I can't do this" scenario.

Comment: On a side note: E.g. in erlang the single underscore is the anonymous variable. It is the only variable which can be re-assigned (or "matched"), unlike other variables, as erlang doesn't allow destructive assignment (which generally speaking is an abomination and weakens the veil between us and the nether realms, where HE waits behind the wall in his palace built of tortured glass).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes matplotlib requires `range(len(y))`, e.g., while `y=array([1,2,5,6])`, `plot(y)` works fine, `scatter(y)` does not.  One has to write `scatter(range(len(y)),y)`.  (Personally, I think this is a bug in `scatter`; `plot` and its friends `scatter` and `stem` should use the same calling sequences as much as possible.)

Answer (score 2):

It's nice to have when you need to use the index for some kind of manipulation and having the current element doesn't suffice. Take for instance a binary tree that's stored in an array. If you have a method that asks you to return a list of tuples that contains each nodes direct children then you need the index.

```
#0 -> 1,2 : 1 -> 3,4 : 2 -> 5,6 : 3 -> 7,8 ...
nodes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
children = []
for i in range(len(nodes)):
  leftNode = None
  rightNode = None
  if i*2 + 1 < len(nodes):
    leftNode = nodes[i*2 + 1]
  if i*2 + 2 < len(nodes):
    rightNode = nodes[i*2 + 2]
  children.append((leftNode,rightNode))
return children
```

Of course if the element you're working on is an object, you can just call a get children method. But yea, you only really need the index if you're doing some sort of manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you really **don't care about the collection itself**. For instance, creating a simple model fit line to compare an "approximation" with the raw data:

```
fib_raw = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21] # Fibonacci numbers

phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
phi2 = (1 - sqrt(5)) / 2

def fib_approx(n): return (phi**n - phi2**n) / sqrt(5)

x = range(len(data))
y = [fib_approx(n) for n in x]

# Now plot to compare fib_raw and y
# Compare error, etc
```

In this case, the values of the Fibonacci sequence itself were irrelevant. All we needed here was the size of the input sequence we were comparing with.

Comment: I am new to Python, what do the ** do in this case? I have read about *args and **kwargs, but this looks different.

Comment: Exponentiation. phi to the power of n.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to iterate over the first `len(a)` items of an object `b` (that is larger than `a`), you should probably use `range(len(a))`:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    do_something_with(b[i])
```

Comment: This might be clearer: `for b_elem in b[:len(a)]:...`

Comment: @aquirdturtle Perhaps it's clearer, but your solution creates a new list, which may be expensive if b & a are large.

Comment: This should be handled using ``itertools.islice`` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have an use case I don't believe any of your examples cover.

```
boxes = [b1, b2, b3]
items = [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5]
for j in range(len(boxes)):
    boxes[j].putitemin(items[j])
```

I'm relatively new to  python though so  happy to  learn a more elegant approach.

Comment: My ignorance. There's zip, a much more pythonic way of iterating over 2 lists in parallel.

Comment: Hah, I came here with a really similar use case... `[a - b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]` is so much nicer than `[list1[i] - list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]`.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example:

```
def loadById(self, id):
    if id in range(len(self.itemList)):
        self.load(self.itemList[id])
```

I can't think of a solution that does not use the range-len composition quickly.

But probably instead this should be done with `try .. except` to stay pythonic i guess..

Comment: `if id < len(self.itemList)`  But `try...except` is better, as you say.

Comment: This does not account for id < 0.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with `for i, num in enumerate(a)` is that `num` does not change when you change `a[i]`. For example, this loop:

```
for i, num in enumerate(a):
    while num > 0:
        a[i] -= 1
```

will never end.
Of course, you could still use enumerate while swapping each use of `num` for `a[i]`, but that kind of defeats the whole purpose of enumerate, so using `for i in range(len(a))` just becomes more logical and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Having a `range` of indices is useful for some more sophisticated problems in combinatorics. For example, to get all possible partitions of a list into three non-empty sections, the most straightforward approach is to find all possible *combinations of distinct endpoints* between the first and second section and between the second and third section. This is equivalent to ordered pairs of integers chosen from the valid indices into the list (except zero, since that would make the first partition empty). Thus:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> def three_parts(sequence):
...     for i, j in combinations(range(1, len(sequence)), 2):
...         yield (sequence[:i], sequence[i:j], sequence[j:])
... 
>>> list(three_parts('example'))
[('e', 'x', 'ample'), ('e', 'xa', 'mple'), ('e', 'xam', 'ple'), ('e', 'xamp', 'le'), ('e', 'xampl', 'e'), ('ex', 'a', 'mple'), ('ex', 'am', 'ple'), ('ex', 'amp', 'le'), ('ex', 'ampl', 'e'), ('exa', 'm', 'ple'), ('exa', 'mp', 'le'), ('exa', 'mpl', 'e'), ('exam', 'p', 'le'), ('exam', 'pl', 'e'), ('examp', 'l', 'e')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why no one mentioned its usefulness for keeping track of the element's index without having to add a counter inside the loop.

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(f"Current element: \"{lst[i]}\". Element index: \"{i}\".")

'''
Output:
Current element: "a". Element index: "0".
Current element: "b". Element index: "1".
Current element: "c". Element index: "2".
'''
```

Edit: this can also be done with `enumerate`:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    print(f"Current element: \"{elem}\". Element index: \"{i}\".")
```

Same output.

Answer (score -1):

My code is:

```
s=["9"]*int(input())
for I in range(len(s)):
    while not set(s[I])<=set('01'):s[i]=input(i)
print(bin(sum([int(x,2)for x in s]))[2:])
```

It is a binary adder but I don't think the range len or the inside can be replaced to make it smaller/better.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's useful for tqdm if you have a large loop and you want to track progress. This will output a progress bar:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

empty_list = np.full(len(items), np.nan)
for i in tqdm(range(len(items))):
    empty_list[i] = do_something(items[i])
```

This will not show progress, at least in the case I was using it for:

```
empty_list = np.full(len(items), np.nan)
for i, _ in tqdm(enumerate(items)):
        empty_list[i] = do_something(items[i])
```

Just showed number of iterations. Not as helpful.