# Python map vs List comprehension Time Complexity

Tags: python-3.x, time, time-complexity, list-comprehension

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

All the integers in this array can be converted into strings individually in the following 3 ways.

1) **Using Str**

```html
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = str(a[i])
print(type(a[0]))
```

2) **Using Map**

```html
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
a = list(map(str,a))
print(type(a[0]))
```

3) **Using List Comprehension**

```html
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
a = [str(i) for i in a]
print(type(a[0]))
```

Can I know what is the time complexity in all the 3 cases to find out which method is efficient? I am a bit confused about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) first.

Comment: @Amadan, Thanks for letting me know, I have edited the same

Comment: What is the difference between (1) and (3)? Also, the time complexity is exactly the same: O(N).

Comment: @Amadan, there was a mistake in the edit, I have now edited them properly. 1 and 3 are different snippets now

Comment: Still same O(N).

Comment: regarding `range(len(list))`, check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19184335/10197418). otherwise, besides time complexity, it's sometimes a good idea to use `timeit` to check the performace of different options that give the same result.

Comment: @Amadan, I have another general query...... When I insert some elements in the dictionary, it automatically gets sorted....so, for inserting n elements the time complexity is O(n) or O(nlogn)?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#dict — amortised cost is O(1) per single dict insert.