# How to multiply each integer "one by one" and display result "in progressive order" until all integers multiplied leads to the overall product

Tags: python-3.x, multiplication

Recently, I've tried creating a for loop that multiplies each integer in the list and returns each sequential product until the overall product of all integers is given.

```
import operator
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce


s = list(map(int, input('Enter numbers WITH SPACES: ').split(' ')))


progression_product = [];
for i in s:
      progression_product.append(reduce(mul, s[0:i]))

#This loop below removes repeating results. As for progressive order multiplication of positive
#integers. It's impossible to have a repeating result.(excluding multiple 1's and 0)

for ss in progression_product:
  if progression_product.count(ss) > 1:
    progression_product.remove(ss)

print(progression_product)
```

-
Notice that the output skips the result for 13 below. But finishes correctly for the overall product of all integers at the end of the listed output

```
Enter numbers WITH SPACES: 12 2 3 4 13 133
[24, 72, 288, 497952]
> 12*2*3*4*13
>3744
```

### Question

Is there any way to fix this bug? Why would python skip the result at 13? And, how do I fix it?

Comment: Your problem is in this: `for i in s:`  It most definitely does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the elements of s, not the indexes. Print the list before removing the duplicates, it will be:

```
[497952, 24, 72, 288, 497952, 497952]
# Which are the products of:
[s[0:12], s[0:2], s[0:3], s[0:4], s[0:13], s[0:133]]
```

Replace the first loop by a index loop, either by `range(len(s))` or by `enumerate(s)`:

```
# Either this:
progression_product = [];
for i in range(len(s)):
      progression_product.append(reduce(mul, s[0:i]))

# Or this:
progression_product = [];
for i, v in enumerate(s):
      progression_product.append(reduce(mul, s[0:i]))
```