# How can I change every element in list?

Tags: python

I have an array called mylist, which has 3 elements. And I want to strip() every element in that array. Here is code

```
mylist = ['  A  ', '  B   ', '    C']

for x in len(mylist):
    mylist[x] = mylist[x].strip()

print(mylist)
```

This code gave an error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: in python mostly we create new array with new values and at the end we assing it to the same variable. Using list comprehension it would be `mylist = [x.strip() for x in mylist]` or using `map` it could be `mylist = list(map(str.strip, mylist))`

Comment: pd.DataFrame(mylist)[0].str.strip().tolist()                                                                                                                                        
#: ['A', 'B', 'C']

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that `len(mylist)` returns a single number. You're missing a range function. Personally, I would suggest using enumerate instead.

For example, If you want the same list

```
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = x.strip()
```

If you want a new list

```
lst = [x.strip() for x in mylist]
# or
lst = list(map(str.split, mylist))
```

Answer (score 3):

> ### Method-1: List Comprehenion
>
> You could do this simply by using a list comprehension as follows (which is more pythonic).

```py
[x.strip() for x in mylist]
```

**Output**:

```
['A','B','C']
```

> ### Method-2: Enumerate
>
> Also, if you must use an **`index`** while iterating over a list, I would strongly suggest you to use **`enumerate(mylist)`** as follows.

```py
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = x.strip()
print(mylist)
```

**Output**:

```
['A','B','C']
```

#### Reference

1. [Is there a need for range(len(a))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184335/is-there-a-need-for-rangelena)

Answer (score 2):

Change `len(mylist)` to `range(len(mylist))`

```
mylist = ['  A  ', '  B   ', '    C']

for x in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[x] = mylist[x].strip()

print(mylist)
```

By the way, I would use list comprehension in this case:

```
mylist = ['  A  ', '  B   ', '    C']
newlist = [x.strip() for x in mylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code `for x in len(mylist)` will convert into `for x in 3` which isn't valid. Hence, the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

**Update:**

```py
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = x.strip()
```

Comment: So, what's the solution?

Comment: Solution would be to either enumerate over the list or use `range` function and update according to the requirement. I know I should have included that but was hoping the OP will understand the problem and figure it out. But thanks, have included it in my answer.