# Checking match on two ordered lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I will give the specific case and the generic case so we can help more people:

I have a **list of ordered lists** and another list with the same length as each ordered list. Each list in the list of lists is students' answers from a large-scale evaluation, and the second is the correct answers from the test. I need to check the % of right answers, AKA how many matches are between each item in each of the lists in order. The output should be a list where 1 means there is a match, and 0 there is no match.

Example:

```
list1 = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], ['A', 'C', 'C', 'B']]
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
result = [[1, 1, 1, 1],[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The others have done a fine job detailing how this can be done with list comprehensions. The following code is a beginner-friendly way of getting the same answer.

```
final = []

# Begin looping through each list within list1
for test in list1:

    # Create a list to store each students scores within
    student = []
    for student_ans, correct_ans in zip(test, list2):

        # if student_ans == correct_ans at the same index...
        if student_ans == correct_ans:
            student.append(1)
        else:
            student.append(0)
    
    # Append the student list to the final list
    final.append(student)
```

Comment: As this answer is intended for beginners, it could benefit considerably from an explanation of the code. Additionally, `range(0,n)` should be replaced with `range(n)`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction on range(n). Hopefully the comments provide enough clarification

Comment: Additionally, `range(len(iterable))` is not recommended in Python, and is a trap for inexperienced users. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184335/is-there-a-need-for-rangelena. Happy coding!

Comment: It would be beneficial for them if it was replaced with a more idiomatic construct, such as `enumerate`.

Comment: Would the updated code using `zip` be an appropriate alternative?

Comment: It absolutely would. Great edit!

Comment: I will mark this answer because, as everyone said, it is beginner friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension, like the following

```
results = [[int(value == list2[index]) for index, value in enumerate(i)] for i in list1]
```

This iterates over each element of `list1`, iterating over each element, and checking if its corresponding pair in `list2` is the same.

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is used to avoid `range(len(list1))`, which is not recommended for stylistic reasons.
Equality `==` returns a boolean, and we cast this to an int via [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), which turns `True` into `1` and `False` into `0`.

Output:

```
>>> list1 = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], ['A', 'C', 'C', 'B']]
>>> list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
>>> results = [[int(value == list2[index]) for index, value in enumerate(i)] for i in list1]
>>> print(results)
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write it as a one-liner using list comprehensions

```
output = [[int(answer_given == correct_answer) for answer_given, correct_answer in zip(student, list2)] for student in list1]
```

Comment: While a stylistic choice, `int(condition)` is often preferred over using a ternary conditional of the form `1 if condition else 0`, for brevity. This answer could also benefit from an explanation for future users. By the way, nice trick with `zip`, I'll be using that!

Comment: @iteratedwalls or really, just `answer_given == correct_answer` would do, since `True == 1` and `False == 0`, since `issubclass(bool, int)`

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I've changed it to int(answer_given == correct_answer).
Just using answer_given == correct_answer returns True and False which is not what OP asked for.

Comment: Note that just like in Javascript, if you prepend a boolean variable with `+`, it will be implicitly converted to an integer. However, it may look like a typo to the uninitiated